# Como importar dumps do MySQL em UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

Estou tentando importar um **dump** do MySQL (em UTF-8), gerado no Windows pelo Navicat, em um servidor **CentOS 6.5** com **MySQL 5.5**.

O problema gerado com isso é... ao executar o seguinte comando:

```
mysql -uroot -p database < dump.sql
```

O MySQL importa o arquivo porém não prevalece o enconding UTF-8, e todas as informações com caracteres especiais ficam corrompidas.

Exemplo:

```
'InteligÃªncia de NegÃ³cios'
```

Ao invés de

```
'Inteligência de Negócios'
```

Como devo proceder para importar o arquivo de maneira correta **prevalecendo o encoding UTF-8**

Answer (score 2):

A solução que encontrei para este problema foi utilizar opção `--default-character-set=utf8` no comando de importação, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database

mysql> SOURCE dump.sql
```