# Quando usar ANSI e quando usar UTF-8?

Tags: arquivo, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, ascii, iso-8859-1

É mais vantajoso utilizar um tipo ANSI ao invés de um tipo UTF-8 ou vice-versa? Existe algum ganho em performance ou armazenamento entre os tipos?

Comment: Excelente pergunta, muito mais objetiva que a semi-duplicata que pergunta o porquê de ainda se usar outras coisas, como se UTF-8 fosse solução para tudo. E excelente resposta do @bigown, baseada em fatos, e não em vôo cego (as tais boas práticas).

Comment: Nem acho que minha resposta seja tão boa, só evitei ser tendencioso como a resposta dada na pergunta que você citou que no fim nem respondeu a pergunta de verdade. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28404/101

Comment: Só para fazer o registro: Converti uma tabela do Excel para arquivo TXT com os campos separados por TABS. No arquivo txt os caracteres acentuados apareciam corretamente. Mas quando converti os dados para uma tabela do MySQL (UTF-8) os caracteres acentuados saíram todos bagunçados. Descobri que o arquivo TXT estava definido como UTF-8. Salvei-o, então, como ANSI, joguei no MySQL de novo e os caracteres acentuados apareceram corretamente. Eis ai um exemplo de como o ANSI resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### TL;DR

1. UTF-8 é um esquema largamente utilizado ao passo que ANSI é praticamente obsoleto.
2. ANSI usa um único *byte* ao passo que UTF-8 usa uma codificação *multibyte*.
3. UTF-8 pode representar uma gama de caracteres muito maior que o bastante limitado ANSI.
4. Pontos de código UTF-8 são uniformemente padronizados enquanto que o ANSI possui muitas diferentes versões.

---

### Diferença entre ANSI e UTF-8

ANSI e UTF-8 são dois esquemas de codificação de caracteres largamente utilizados em um momento ou outro.

A principal diferença entre eles é que UTF-8 foi criado para ser mais ou menos equivalente ao ANSI mas sem todas as muitas desvantagens que este tinha. Ambos os esquemas expandem o conjunto básico de caracteres ASCII, o que significa que até os 127 caracteres iniciais, eles são basicamente equivalentes.

A primeira desvantagem do ANSI é o uso de *bytes* fixos para representar os caracteres. Em comparação, UTF-8 é mais flexível por ser um esquema de codificação *multibyte*.

Dependendo das necessidades do usuário, qualquer ponto de código entre 1 e 6 *bytes* podem ser usados para representar um caracteres. Porque o ANSI usa apenas um *byte* (ou 8 *bits*), ele só consegue representar um máximo de 256 caracteres, o que não chega nem perto dos 1.112.064 de caracteres, códigos de controle e *slots* reservados que o formato Unicode pode representar com o esquema UTF-8.

Usando codificação *multibyte* torna possível acomodar todos esses pontos de código e ainda assim consumir o mínimo de memória. O primeiro *byte* do UTF-8 casa exatamente com o ASCII e, por conta disso, os caracteres mais comuns requerem apenas um *byte*.

Para acomodar mais caracteres, haviam múltiplas páginas ANSI criadas para diferentes idiomas. Você não podia, portanto, usar certos caracteres uma vez que eles não pertenciam às mesmas páginas de codificação.

Isso também requeria ao programa saber de antemão qual página seria usada ou caracteres incorretos apareceriam.

UTF-8 não tem nenhum desses problemas uma vez que possui seu próprio ponto de código.

UTF-8 é superior ao ANSI de todas as maneiras. Não existe motivo para se preferir ANSI ao invés de UTF-8 ao criar aplicações as quais possam ser decodificadas por todos os computadores. A única razão plausível seria a execução de um aplicativo antigo o qual você não tenha um substituto viável para ele.

**Fonte:** [Difference Between](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/protocols-formats/difference-between-ansi-and-utf-8/)

**Tradução:** Eu, eu mesmo, e nada da Irene :p

Answer (score 30):

> Quando usar ANSI e quanto usar UTF-8?

Estritamente falando quando você usa UTF-8 está adotando o *set* de caracteres ANSI. Mas eu acho que você está usando o termo ANSI erroneamente. Não é culpa sua, há muitos anos o termo está sendo usado de forma errada. Provavelmente você está querendo comparar UTF-8 e ISO-8859-1/Latin 1 (que costuma ser confundido com CP1252/Windows-1252 que é outro *encoding/charset* que serve o mesmo propósito e que tem características essencialmente idênticas).

O primeiro critério para escolher um ou outro é verificar com quem você vai trocar estes dados. Não adianta nada pensar em qual é melhor quando ele é incompatível com a atividade que ele será usado. Determine o requisito da **compatibilidade com que será intercambiado e não se preocupe com mais nada**. Se você não tem problemas de compatibilidade com nada, [use o mais simples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Se você tem total controle de como será feito o intercâmbio ou tem liberdade de escolha, para evitar conversões procure **escolher a forma que as tecnologias usadas por você preferem**. Se ainda isso é escolha sua aí vamos analisar outros pontos.

> É mais vantajoso utilizar um tipo ANSI ao invés de um tipo UTF-8 ou vice-versa?

Vou começar discordando da resposta do Bruno quando diz que o "ANSI" está praticamente obsoleto. Ainda há muitos casos que ele não só pode ser usado, como é obrigatório. É claro que há uma onda de preferência pelo UTF-8. Isto é inegável. Mas ambos são ferramentas úteis e serão utilizados por muito tempo.

Não há dúvidas que o UTF-8 é mais moderno, mais flexível, mais completo, mais confiável na maioria dos casos e [mais popular](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all), mas fica a questão se tudo isto é necessário. A **maior vantagem do "ANSI" é a sua simplicidade para a maioria dos casos**.

O "ANSI" ainda tem as vantagens de performance e armazenamento discutidas abaixo.

A **maior vantagem do UTF-8 é a universalidade** (que é relativa, não quer dizer que realmente serve para tudo, serve para todos os caracteres) e isto tem um significado ainda maior conforme ele vai ficando mais popular. Essa universalidade se dá pelo fato de permitir vários *bytes* para representar 1 caractere, ao mesmo que tempo que isto acaba sendo a sua principal desvantagem, o causador da maioria das dificuldades do *encoding*. Com mais *bytes* pode-se representar uma quantidade muito grande caracteres sem recorrer a artifícios. E a flexibilidade permite que o espaço ocupado não seja tão grande apesar de acabar consumindo mais processamento para processar a maioria dos algoritmos.

Mas além de ter uma implementação pesada, muitas vezes com defeitos de tão complexo que é, por definição existe a possibilidade de ambiguidades de formas para representar o mesmo caractere, que causa problemas em comparações (o que você vê não é o que está representado na *string*) e uma *string* pode se tornar inválida em casos de perda de parte da informação com truncamento. Não vou nem dizer que usar UTF-8 é extremamente complexo e pouquíssimos programadores sabem usá-lo corretamente. Tudo bem que não precisa entender tudo para o caso que garantidamente usará apenas o simples, mas aí o UTF-8 não é tão vantajoso assim. Curiosamente os povos que mais se beneficiaram com ele são os que mais reclamam dele.

Um dos problemas citados é a confusão em comprimento em *bytes* da *string* e o comprimento em caracteres (ou *code points* como são realmente chamados). A maioria dos programadores não sabe bem o que a função/método `Length` de uma *string* retorna. De fato isso pode variar de acordo com a tecnologia usada.

Há outros problemas citados em [Por que ainda se usam outras codificações além do UTF-8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23815/101).

É possível abstrair o tratamento de *codepages* do "ANSI" se for necessário. Na imensa maioria das vezes elas não são necessárias, mas se for dá para criar uma estrutura de dados que encapsule e abstraia esse tratamento de forma transparente para o usuário da *string*. Claro que não é perfeito, não resolve todos os problemas mas resolve um dos problemas citados. Mas o UTF-8 também não resolve todos os problemas. Por que ninguém fez isto (pelo menos nada público e bem conhecido)? Porque não é uma necessidade real na maioria dos casos.

Por fim, de qual versão do UTF-8 estamos falando? É, ele tem versões. Tem retrocompatibilidade entre elas, mas se você tentar pegar algo gerado com uma versão mais nova usando um recurso novo e manipular com uma implementação antiga, terá dificuldades.

> Existe algum ganho em performance ou armazenamento entre os tipos?

Certamente o "ANSI" é mais rápido e ocupa menos espaço que o UTF-8. Em casos específicos onde somente caracteres da tabela ASCII (até 127) sejam usados o UTF-8 pode ocupar o mesmo espaço.

Há a garantia que o "ANSI" ocupa 1 *byte*, o UTF-8 não. Fica claro que o UTF-8 não só a ocupação de espaço é maior mas o tempo para processar também. Quando você pode garantir o tamanho em *bytes* dos caracteres dá para ser mais eficiente. É possível ter alguns algoritmos mais ou menos eficientes com UTF-8 mas a necessidade de tratar tamanhos diferentes gera um custo adicional. Não existe milagre. Podemos dizer, a grosso modo, que "ANSI" é um *array* e UTF-8 é uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101) diretamente em sequência. Não há como chegar em um caractere em UTF-8 sem passar por outros caracteres. Mesmo o caractere individual exige uma verificação para saber se há um complemento para ele, possivelmente através de um *branch* no processador, que é bem caro.

É indiscutível qual ganha em performance. Dá para discutir se ela é importante. A diferença não costuma ser tão grande e outros fatores podem tornar a diferença ainda mais irrisória. Mas também há problemas que requerem a performance extrema.

O espaço ocupado é maior com UTF-8 mas a diferença não costuma ser tão grande (e se for, provavelmente você não tem muita escolha, o que é altamente improvável no mundo ocidental). Mas se existir alguma razão real que o tamanho seja importante, opte pelo "ANSI".

Basicamente a diferença acontecerá nos caracteres acentuados. No "ANSI" o caractere sempre ocupará 1 *byte* e no UTF-8 ocupará 2 *bytes*. Não vou comparar nada além dos acentos porque o "ANSI" não conseguirá manipular. Estamos falando de situações onde você tem escolha. Para conhecer a [tabela de acentos permitidos, veja na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout). Note que os caracteres sem acento, ou seja, constantes da tabela ASCII, o UTF-8 ocupará apenas 1 *byte*. A maioria dos caracteres usados não possuem acento.

O que talvez possa complicar na decisão é o tamanho variável. Existem formatos de arquivos que exigem um tamanho fixo dos campos/linhas. Mas neste caso provavelmente também há o requisito para o *encoding* e/ou *charset*.

## Conclusão

Lembre-se que o assunto é extremamente complexo, para falar tudo que seria necessário daria um livro inteiro (sem exagero).

Particularmente eu procuro usar o ISO-8859-1 em tudo o que eu faço onde tenho liberdade total. Ele é mais simples, mais fácil, mais eficiente e resolve todos os problemas que eu tenho nos softwares que eu faço. Infelizmente por um motivo ou outro acabo sendo forçado a usar o UTF-8 ou mesmo UTF-16 (este não para arquivos a não ser que realmente seja necessário) em algumas situações. Nenhum grande problema, já foi demonstrado que há vantagens nele também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).