# É possíver evitar o uso de "if"s nestes casos?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, if, estilo-de-codificação, else

Tenho lido muitos materiais na internet sobre OOP, a esmagadora maioria diz para evitar `if/else` a todo custo. Para um iniciante em OOP como eu, surgem muitas dúvidas.

Por exemplo:

```
if (comboBoxUF.SelectedItem == null)
{
    return;
}
```

Como não usar `if`s nestes casos?

Ou nestes:

```
if (ctrl is ToolStripMenuItem)
{
    GetMenuItems((ToolStripMenuItem)ctrl , items);
}
```

Seria realmente possível não usar programação procedural ao desenvolver uma aplicação em C#?

Comment: Relacionado >> [Por que em algumas situações if's são considerados ruins?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/91)

Comment: if else simples não tem problema nenhum problema começa quando você coloca muitos aninhados e acaba dando uma complexidade na hora do entendimento do código.

Comment: @EduardoSampaio embora você esteja correto, a questão citada nesta pergunta não é bem essa, é uma comparação com o modo OOP de fazer as coisas onde se prefere o polimorfismo ao desvio de fluxo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Mitos

Você está aprendendo que a esmagadora maioria das coisas que você lê por aí não faz sentido. Pelo menos não sem ter uma boa explicação que faça sentido.

Se disseram que algo é bom ou ruim e não disseram porque, provavelmente estão inventando ou passando pra frente algo que viram em algum lugar, não entenderam e deram sua versão, criando um ["telefone sem fio"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefone_sem_fio_(brincadeira)). Imagine que isso vai piorando.

Se ver algo assim é bom questionar em bons lugares, onde as respostas podem ser avaliadas por outras pessoas. Um desses lugares é aqui mesmo. Questionando é que se aprende.

O primeiro problema é as pessoas venderem OOP como solução para tudo, como se fosse um paradigma máximo que deve ser sempre seguido, e pior, que deve segui-lo puramente, mesmo em linguagens que não são puramente orientadas a objeto. É bom fazer OOP o que faz sentido. Um mito comum, inclusive, é vender certas linguagens como orientadas a objeto em sua essência. Nenhuma linguagem *mainstream* tem como principal paradigma a orientação a objeto, mas várias fazem este marketing (fuja de marketing, não necessariamente da linguagem). Na verdade [é questionável se existe alguma linguagem OO pura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

Isso é importante porque a pergunta é sobre usar OOP para evitar o `if`. Existe a *tag*, cita o paradigma como referência base do problema e pede para comparar com outro paradigma.

## `if` pode ser ruim

De fato [a manutenção pode sofrer se abusar do uso de `ifs`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/101) (tem ótimas respostas sobre o problema real, não vou repetir aqui). Existem algumas formas de evitá-los que facilitam a manutenção dos softwares, especialmente quando estamos falando de regras de negócio que podem ser mutáveis, que façam parte de uma API pública. A principal forma é através de polimorfismo.

Quando estamos falando de detalhe de implementação aí muda de figura. Ainda não quer dizer que devemos abusar de `ifs`. Mas também não podemos abusar de outros mecanismos quando o `if` é bem adequado.

Note que dizem para evitar todo o mecanismo do `if` substituindo por OOP. Não adianta nada substituir o `if` por um mecanismo que faz a mesma coisa, como o `switch` ou *pattern matching* (disponível no C# 7), por exemplo. A ideia que estão "vendendo" é que tenha **nenhum** desvio do fluxo de execução, sempre, que é característica de linguagens imperativas, exceto funções.

Isso também é pregado pelas linguagens funcionais, o que faz mais sentido.

## Como eliminar o `if` nos exemplos citados

Tá certo que não vi o contexto deles, mas em C#, eu não sei como fazer os códigos apresentados sem o uso do `if`, não só porque eles usam coisas que foram desenvolvidas com claro intuito de serem usadas em `if`s, mas também porque não vejo o que poderia ficar melhor sem o uso deles.

Talvez vendo o contexto completo de onde estejam estes códigos, aí esses `ifs` específicos podem não ser necessários ou pelo menos eles poderiam ser modificados, ainda que acho improvável que dê para fazer algo muito melhor.

Um bom indicativo como é difícil fazer isto está na resposta do Cigano. Ele tentou dar dois exemplos sem o `if` e não conseguiu. Um deles o `if` continua lá e o outro só substituiu por um `switch` que é até mais criticado que o `if` em si pelos defensores de OOP, já que ele é até mais usado para substituir o polimorfismo que o próprio `if`.

#### Primeiro exemplo

Você tem que tomar uma decisão dependendo se o valor é nulo. Tem como fazer algumas construções diferentes que podem ser feitas, mas todas usariam um `if` ou algo parecido.

A única forma de evitar é garantir que o objeto nunca seria nulo, aí é óbvio que o `if` não seria necessário. Pode garantir nesse caso? Acho que não.

Em C# 8 pode garantir que um objeto não seja nulo. Mesmo assim será algo opcional e é possível que este caso faça sentido ele poder ter valor `null`.

Em C# 7 pode usar *pattern matching* para estabelecer nulidade e no 9 a não nulidade.

Ali tomar uma decisão pode ser uma regra de negócio. Não é fácil eliminar essa possibilidade.

#### Segundo exemplo

Até indica ser possível eliminar o `if` garantindo que este código só rode dentro de um `ToolStripMenuItem`. Uma técnica de especialização poderia ser aplicada. Então teria um método que só aceitaria esse tipo, portanto ele só seria chamado com um objeto desse tipo. Aí a verificação e o *cast* não seriam necessários. Obviamente seria necessário um outro método mais geral para executar quando o objeto é um controle diferente.

Esse `if` existe por pragmatismo. Se quase todo o código é igual entre os controles, ele é aproveitado e apenas faz um desvio no caso específico. Se é o melhor ou não, depende de ver o todo, apenas posso dizer que parece ser melhor.

Muitas vezes para usar essa técnica evita-se o reuso e até gera-se duplicação de código que pode ferir a manutenção de forma pior. Aí pode-se cometer um pecado maior. Para cumprir uma regra boba pode-se preferir um código todo complicado.

Seria algo assim (sem contexto fica difícil):

```
public string GetControlXXX(ToolStripMenuItem ctrl) { //talvez poderia até ter outro nome
    ...
    GetMenuItems(ctrl , items);
    ...
    return ...;
 }
 public string GetControlXXX(Control ctrl) {
    ...
    //faz alguma coisa com ctrl, mas não precisa ver se é um ToolStripMenuItem
    ...
    return ...;
 }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Overload.cs).

Obviamente que o problema precisaria fazer sentido ter esses dois métodos, não estou dizendo que o caso faz, é provável até que nesse exemplo específico não faça mesmo.

Outra forma hipotética é se a arquitetura do seu *framework* trabalhasse diferente. O que poderia evitar o `if`, mas criaria outras dificuldades no código.

## Outra linguagem

Se fosse outra linguagem seria diferente, mesmo assim não dá pra fazer milagre, não quer dizer que o código sairia melhor sempre.

Linguagens onde a resolução da chamada de função possa se dar pelo valor do argumento pode eliminar `ifs`. Mas isso não quer dizer que seja uma coisa boa. Como a resolução será feita em tempo de execução, até mesmo onde não precisaria, a performance vai pagar.

E ainda existe outro problema já mencionado mais acima: ou teria repetições de código, ou o código teria tantas indireções que seria difícil entendê-lo.

## Paradigmas

Linguagens puramente orientadas a objeto possuem `if`, mesmo que de forma mais disfarçada.

É possível usar programação procedural ou não procedural em C#, mas acho que isso nada tem a ver com o problema e foi apenas colocado por equivoco na pergunta. Em essência não é possível programar em C# sem usar o paradigma [imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101). Tecnicamente até é possível, mas é inviável tentar fazer isso, até porque OOP é um paradigma secundário.

## Conclusão

Evitar `if` a **todo custo** é bem forte, né? Vamos salvar a vida de uma pessoa a todo custo? Mesmo que signifique matar 200?

O certo é fazer o que fica fácil de ler, entender, dar manutenção (até isso tem hora certa pra questionar). E nenhuma regra fixa e única consegue dar uma resposta definitiva. Um conjunto de técnicas aplicadas corretamente na medida certa em cada caso ajuda atingir esse objetivo.

Regras bobas:

- [Por que devo usar apenas um "return" em cada função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/101)
- [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101)
- [Por que o uso do "break" é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/101)
- [Deve-se usar break em for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/101)
- [Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101)
- [Quando usar ANSI e quando usar UTF-8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27519/101)
- [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101)
- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)
- [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101)
- [Principal objetivo de classes utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101)
- [Até que ponto a otimização prematura é um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101)
- [$GLOBALS para armazenar configurações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102402/101)
- [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101)

Comment: bigown, muito obrigado pela resposta. Excelente explicação.

Comment: @Robss70 ainda vou melhorar algumas coisas, mas basicamente é isto.

Answer (score 4):

A todo custo não. Eu diria que em várias situações eles são evitáveis sim. A ideia é estabelecer uma disciplina de programação que não complique seu código desnecessariamente.

Vou mostrar alguns casos em que o uso de `if` pode ser evitado.

## 1. Quando o fluxo retorna algo

Do seu exemplo (um pouco modificado):

```
    if (comboBoxUF.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        return "É nulo";
    }

    return "Não é nulo";
```

Repare que, se eu escrevesse o `else`, não faria a menor diferença. O resultado seria o mesmo. Existe um outro erro que o compilador do C# pode pegar chamado:

> Not all code paths return a value.

Ele é mais comum em situações que o código contenha `if` e `else`, e o método ou função precisa retornar um valor.

## 2. Quando o teste envolve uma relação finita de valores

Este é o famoso caso de testes como o abaixo:

```
int valor = new Random().Next(1, 5);
if (valor == 1) { ... }
else if (valor == 2) { ... }
// E assim por diante
```

Um `switch` é melhor estruturado neste caso:

```
int valor = new Random().Next(1, 5);
switch (valor)
{
    case 1: 
        // Faz alguma coisa
        break;
    case 2:
        // Faz outra coisa
        break;
    default: // Neste contexto, seria como um else
        // Faz mais outra coisa
        break;
}
```

---

## Casos em que ele não tem como ser evitado

Basicamente, qualquer coisa que exija desvio de fluxo. Você colocou um muito bom: teste de herança.

```
    if (ctrl is ToolStripMenuItem)
    {
        GetMenuItems((ToolStripMenuItem)ctrl, items);
    }
```

Recursões também são bons exemplos:

```
public static int Fibonacci(int numero)
{
    if (numero == 0) return 0;
    if (numero == 1) return 1;
    return Fibonacci(numero - 2) + Fibonacci(numero - 1);
}
```

Comment: Cigano, nos casos de uma classe que valida controles de um form o if seria o mais viável ?

Comment: Depende do que você precisa fazer. Se for verificação de herança, acredito que sim.

Comment: No caso seria validação se o controle está vazio, ou se contém um valor válido.

Comment: Então sim. Não sei como poderia ser feito de outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Oque essa "maioria esmagadora" quis dizer é que é melhor fazer assim:

É melhor fazer assim:

`player_x += Sign(player_direcao); //Caso a direção seja 10 retorna 1, caso seja -20 retorna -1 e caso seja 0 retorna 0.`

Do que assim:

```
if(player_direcao > 0)
{
player_x ++;
}
else if(player_direcao < 0)
{
player_x --;
}
```