# Problemas de compatibilização de charset iso-8859-1 e utf-8

Tags: php, html, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

- A 1ª Imagem utilizo o charset=iso-8859-1

<kbd>[image: exemplo com charset=iso-8859-1]</kbd>

- Nesta 2ª imagem utilizo o utf8

<kbd>[image: exemplo com charset=utf-8]</kbd>

Tenho um sistema de notícias em que é possível colar html ou texto de outras páginas.
Na página em que as noticias são apresentadas utilizo o `charset=iso-8859-1` por causa da acentuação mas ao utilizar este charset os menus e restantes títulos ficam alterados devido à acentuçao.

Precisava da vossa ajuda para saber se é possivel ter dois metas charset na mesma página ou numa parte da página ou outra forma de contornar a situção.

Para além disso tenho dois ficheiros de conexao:

```
global $databases;
$databases = array( 
    'local' => array
    (
            'host'=>'localhost',
            'port'=>3306,
            'dbname'=>'noticiass',
            'user'=>'root',
            'password'=>''
    )
);
```

mysql.php

```
Class mysql
{

    public $query;
    public $data;
    public $result;
    public $rows;   
    public $page = 0;
    public $perpage = 10;
    public $current = 1;
    public $url;
    public $link = '';
    public $total = '';
    public $pagination = false;

    protected $config;
    protected $host;
    protected $port;
    protected $user;
    protected $pass;
    protected $dbname;
    protected $con;



    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            #array com dados do banco
            include 'database.conf.php';
            global $databases;
            $this->config = $databases['local'];
            # Recupera os dados de conexao do config
            $this->dbname = $this->config['dbname'];
            $this->host = $this->config['host'];
            $this->port = $this->config['port'];
            $this->user = $this->config['user'];
            $this->pass = $this->config['password'];
            # instancia e retorna objeto
            $this->con = mysql_connect( "$this->host", "$this->user", "$this->pass" );
            mysql_select_db( "$this->dbname" );
            if ( !$this->con )
            {
                throw new Exception( "Falha na conexão MySql com o banco [$this->dbname] em database.conf.php" );
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->con;
            }
            $this->url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function query( $query = '' )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( $query == '' )
            {
                throw new Exception( 'mysql query: A query deve ser informada como parâmetro do método.' );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->query = $query;
                if($this->pagination == true){  
                    $this->result = mysql_query( $this->query );
                    $this->fetchAll();
                    $this->paginateLink();
                    $this->query .= " LIMIT $this->page, $this->perpage";
                    $this->pagination = false;

                }
                $this->result = mysql_query( $this->query );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $this->data = "";
        $this->rows = 0;
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $this->result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
        {
            $this->data[] = $row;
        }
        if ( isset( $this->data[0] ) )
        {
            $this->rows = count( $this->data );
        }
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function rowCount()
    {
        return @mysql_affected_rows();
    }    

    public function getUrl($perpage)
    {
        $this->url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return $this;
    }   
    public function paginate($perpage)
    {
        $this->pagination = true;
        $this->perpage = $perpage;
        return $this;
    }
    public function paginateLink()
    {   
        if(!preg_match('/\?/',$this->url))
        {
            $this->url .= "?";
        }else{
            $this->url .= "&";
        }
        if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) )
        {
            $this->current = $_GET['page'];
            $this->page = $this->perpage * $_GET['page'] - $this->perpage;
            if ( $_GET['page'] == 1 )
            {
                $this->page = 0;
            }
        }
        $this->total = $this->rows;
        if ( $this->rows > $this->perpage )
        {                           
            $this->link = "<div class=\"pagination\"><ul>";
            $prox = "javascript:;";
            $ant = "javascript:;";
            if ( $this->current >= 2 )
            {
                $ant = $this->url."page=" . ($this->current - 1);
            }
            if ( $this->current >= 1 && $this->current < ($this->total / $this->perpage))
            {
                $prox = $this->url."page=" . ($this->current + 1);
            }
            $this->link .= '<li><a href="' . $ant . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
            $from = round( $this->total / $this->perpage );
            if($from == 1){$from++;}

            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $from ; $i++ )
            {
                if ( $this->current == $i )
                {
                    $this->link .= "<li class=\"active\"><a>$i</a></li>\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->link .= "<li><a href=\"".$this->url."page=$i\">$i</a></li>\n";
                }
            }
            $this->link .= '<li><a href="' . $prox . '">&raquo;</a></li>';
            $this->link .= "</ul>\n";
            $this->link .= "</div>\n";
        }   
        return $this;
    }

    public function cut($str,$chars,$info=  '')
    {
        if ( strlen( $str ) >= $chars )
        {
            $str = preg_replace( '/\s\s+/', ' ', $str );
            $str = strip_tags( $str );
            $str = preg_replace( '/\s\s+/', ' ', $str );
            $str = substr( $str, 0, $chars );
            $str = preg_replace( '/\s\s+/', ' ', $str );
            $arr = explode( ' ', $str );
            array_pop( $arr );
            //$arr = preg_replace('/\&nbsp;/i',' ',$arr);
            $final = implode( ' ', $arr ) . $info;
        }
        else
        {
            $final = $str;
        }
        return $final;
    }

}
```

Comment: Artigo relacionado : http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29

Comment: Amigo, pra não ter problemas com charset, sempre defina o mesmo charset pro banco de dados(collate), para os campos das tabelas e no header da página. Esse problema com charset é comum quando a página esta em uma codificação e os dados do banco em outra. 

Dois charsets na mesma página não tem como

Comment: O padrão universal de charset é utf8, para qualquer linguagem, não use iso-8859-1, o utf8 já interpreta acentuação. Para todo o caso, você deve usar tudo no padrão utf8, inclusive no banco de dados, e os encodes de arquivos também, devem ser encodados em utf8, assim você vai parar de sofrer com isso. E se tiver no fomato iso-8859-1, converta para utf8... experimente conversões nessa ordem de preferência:  `utf8_encode()` > `html_entity_decode()` > `htmlentities()` e em último caso, se nada disso funcionar, use o `header('content-type text/html charset=utf-8');`

Comment: E para o header do seu documento HTML, use a meta tag: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: E antes que eu me esqueça, nada de fazer isso no php.ini: `php_admin_value default_charset ISO-8859-1`

Comment: Duplicada complicada: ver mais simples e objetiva em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8442/4186  ... Não tenha dúvida, use sempre e apenas **UTF-8**!

Comment: @PeterKrauss como assim? O que tem de complicado? Está dividido por tópicos e explicado fatores importantes, desde conexão, header e codificação dos documentos, é só seguir um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Eu uso UTF-8 onde precisa e iso-8859-1 e até win-1252 onde é mais conveniente, pq eu realmente conheço bem de encodings e entendo os pontos fortes e fracos de cada um, a ponto de saber que não tem solução que sirva para todos os cenários. Infelizmente tem gente que se vende pelo discurso da bala de prata e acha que existe solução universal. Eu até entendo que quando o cara é só teórico é meio complicado de entender essas coisas, pq a pessoa tem que realmente estudar demais, e nem todo mundo o faz. Sai mais "barato" adotar verdades absolutas.

Comment: Vou deixar o [link do artigo do Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) atualizado que o Guilherme comentou. Achei [uma tradução pt-BR](https://medium.com/@sestrem/o-m%C3%ADnimo-que-todo-desenvolvedor-deve-saber-sobre-unicode-e-character-sets-789a4229ecf5) para algum interessado.

Answer (score 154):

Em uma rápida resposta: **não** é possível.

No momento que a página começa a renderizar, ela já assume uma codificação (ou tenta detectá-la acaso não seja declarada, geralmente usa o padrão do servidor).

### Os problemas comuns da codificação

É muito comum quando estamos trabalhando com acentos nos depararmos com caracteres estranhos como por exemplo:

- Algo semelhante a `Ã©` (que representa o `é`) ou `Ã£` (que representa `ã`), isto ocorre porque o caractere é *unicode*, mas a página está em iso-8859-1 (ou outro compatível).
- E o sinal `�` um exemplo de situação é quando você usa um acentos compatíveis com iso-8859-1 em uma página que esta tentando processar UTF-8 devido ao `Content-Type: ...; charset=utf8`.

### Sobre o iso-8859-1

Eu recomendo usar `iso-8859-1` se o seu site for *"100% em Português"* e você não necessite de "codificações extras" (como por exemplo emojis), no entanto mesmo sendo em Português você deve pensar em talvez migrar pro *utf-8*, um dos motivos é que em junho de 2004, o grupo de desenvolvimento da ISO/IEC responsável por sua manutenção declarou o fim do suporte a esta codificação, concentrando-se no UCS e no Unicode.

A seguir irei explicar como usar cada um deles, conforme os tópicos:

- O que é necessário para usar UTF-8
- O que é necessário para usar iso-8859-1/latin1/ansi

---

## O que é necessário para usar UTF-8

- PHP scripts (me refiro aos arquivos no servidor e não a resposta do mesmo) salvos em "utf-8 sem BOM"
- MySQL (ou outro tipo de banco de dados) com `charset=utf-8`
- Preferencialmente defina usando PHP `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

> **Nota:** A vantagem do UTF-8 é que você pode utilizar vários "idiomas" na sua página com caracteres que não são suportados pelo "iso-8859-1".

<sub>Fonte: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1</sub>

Se decidir usar UTF-8 no seu site/projeto, recomendo seguir os seguintes passos:

### Scripts PHP com UTF-8 sem "BOM"

> **Nota:** leia sobre isto em http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark (Inglês)

Você deve salvar todos scripts PHP (até os que você usará com `include`, `require`, etc) em utf-8 sem "BOM", você pode utilizar softwares como [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ou [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) para converter os arquivos:

- Usando notepad++:

  [image: utf8 sem bom notepad++]
- Usando Sublime Text:

  [image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]
- Usando Eclipse vá até <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > <kbd>Workspace</kbd> > <kbd>Text File Encoding</kbd>:

  [image: netbeans]

> **Nota:** que arquivos com extensão `.js` ou `.css` que usam acentos no conteúdo também ser salvos com a mesma codificação que as páginas, da mesma maneira que foi usado para salvar os documentos descritos acima, eventualmente arquivos `.svg` podem ser embarcados então se eles tiverem qualquer acentuação ou caractere diferente também devem ser salvos com a mesma codificação da página

### MySQL com UTF-8

Para criar uma tabela em UTFf-8 no MySQL você deve utilizar algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE minhatabela (
   id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   titulo varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Se as tabelas existem, então primeiro faça um BACKUP delas e depois, utilize um dos seguintes comandos (conforme a necessidade):

- Converte banco de dados:
  `ALTER DATABASE bancodedados CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
- Converte uma tabela especifica:
  `ALTER TABLE minhatabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Além de criar as tabelas em UTF-8 é necessário definir a conexão como UTF-8.

Com PDO é necessário usar [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.exec.php):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BANCO;charset=utf-8', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
$conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');//Define o charset como UTF-8
```

Com o mysqli é necessário usar [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', $mysqli->connect_errno);
    exit;
}

/*
 * compatibilidade para to 5.2.9 e 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (false === $mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```

Com mysqli procedural:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}
```

### Definindo o charset da página

Você pode usar a tag `<meta>` para definir o charset, mas o recomendável é você fazer isto na  resposta da requisição (resposta do servidor), definindo os "headers" (isto não quer dizer que você não deva utilizar `<meta>`).

Para isto, no PHP use a função [`header`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php):

O motivo para se utilizar na resposta do servidor também é por causa do tempo de renderização da página quanto a resposta do servidor e páginas *AJAX* precisam também do charset definido por `header();`.

> Nota: `header();` sempre deve ir no topo do script antes de qualquer `echo`, `print`, ou outro tipo de exibição de conteúdo.

Em arquivos que a resposta deve ser HTML:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

echo 'Conteudo';
```

---

## O que é necessário para usar iso-8859-1/latin1/ansi

Para se usar iso-8859-1, você deve utilizar:

- PHP scripts salvos em "iso-8859-1" (ou windows-1252 e ansi)
- MySQL (ou outro tipo de banco de dados) com `charset=iso-8859-1`
- Preferencialmente defina usando PHP `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

Primeiro deve salvar "todos scripts .php" como iso-8859-1 (ou ANSI) e documentos .html (se houver):

- Para salvar usando notepad++:

  [image: salvando documento em ANSI com notepad++]
- Para salvar usando SublimeText:

  [image: salvando documento em iso-8859-1 ou windows 1252]

### MySQL com Latin1

Quase todos servidores mysql vem configurado para usar por padrão o charset `latin1`, no entanto isto pode ser modificado no `my.ini`, então os passos a seguir sobre mysql são opcionais, pois dependerão do seu `my.ini` estar usando **algo diferente** do `latin1` nas seguintes linhas:

```
[client]
default-character-set=<charset padrão para o cliente>

[mysql]
default-character-set=<charset padrão para o cliente>
```

Então vai precisa definir `latin1`, com PDO é necessário usar [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.exec.php):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BANCO;charset=utf-8', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
$conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET latin1');//Define o charset como UTF-8
```

E com o mysqli é necessário usar [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', $mysqli->connect_errno);
    exit;
}

/*
 * compatibilidade para to 5.2.9 e 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (false === $mysqli->set_charset('latin1')) {
    printf('Error ao usar latin1: %s', $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```

Com mysqli procedural:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'latin1')) {
    printf('Error ao usar latin1: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}
```

### Definindo o charset da página

Basta adcionar para `; charset=iso=8859-1` após o tipo, por exemplo `text/html` ou `application/xml` ou `text/plain`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

echo 'Conteudo';
```

Comment: No mysql também é necessário definir o character set da conexão. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: +1 Acho melhor usar `utf8mb4` no lugar de `utf8` no MySQL, para suportar TODOS os caracteres imagináveis: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: Só uma observação: mesmo o site sendo 100% brasileiro eu não recomendo usar ISO-8859-1, não há necessidade, só dor de cabeça, é que nem tomada de 3 pinos.

Comment: @IvanFerrer obrigado, mas apenas pra ressaltar eu não falei só se for brasileiro eu falei duas coisas: **seu site for "100% brasileiro"** e **se você não necessite de "codificações extras"**, outra que citei foi que iso não tem mais suporte desde 2004 (12 anos) ;)

Comment: Discordo totalmente do Ivan, ISO-8859-1 é tão simples quanto ASCII, e não tem nada da série de desvantagens do UTF. Só não tem caracteres para algumas línguas, emoticons, etc, que são dispensáveis na maior parte das aplicações. E o fato de não ter suporte é no sentido de que não vai ser mais atualizado, pq já estabilizou. O que é uma vantagem.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fechei umas 2 ou 3 ontem como dup dessa sua, se achar que deve, acrescente algum comentário sobre nomes de arquivo também (que dependem do encoding do OS, e não do PHP ou do Apache). Se bem que eu acho que o cara que usa acentuação em arquivo a ser usado por processos automatizados já pede por problemas naturalmente. Depois de ler, pode sinalizar meu comment como obsoleto ou me avisar, que eu deleto.

Comment: Pra quem usa o NetBeans o caminho para codificar o projeto é: Arquivo -> Propriedade do Projeto -> Códigos-fonte -> Codificação

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam ok, vou atualizar depois com imagens. Só tenha em mente que isto é parte da solução apenas, a conexão e os headers também devem ser trabalhados com cautela.

Comment: a minha codificação do PHP e HTML já estavão corretos faltou apenas setar a codificação na conexão com o banco, valeu pela ajuda

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam ótimo, era só pra reforçar mesmo.

Comment: Mas porque isso aconteceu no arquivo da view mas no DAO e no controller não, o problema só ocorreu quando trafeguei os dados via session, se o problema foi não setar a codificação na conexão o erro não deveria acontecer em todos os arquivos? Se achar que devo criar uma pergunta pra isso posso editar a [minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283497/caracteres-acentuados-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-reconhecidos)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não é só no DAO e no controller, como a resposta explica, tem que ter certeza que todos arquivos esteja salvos com a mesma codificação, a conexão deve usar a mesma codificação dos arquivos também e por ai vai ... é provavel que você tenha arquivos em codificações diferentes.

Answer (score 40):

Não é possível. Logo, quando uma página HTML é carregada, informa-se o charset utilizado nela:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Assim sendo, todo conteúdo carregado na página deve, idealmente, ser carregado naquele charset - seja ele UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 ou qualquer outro.

No seu sistema, você deve fornecer uma maneira de sempre armazenar o conteúdo, sempre no mesmo charset. Isso envolve formato do banco de dados, formato dos formulários submetidos - por exemplo, um CMS - e até mesmo os formato dos arquivos de código-fonte do seu site.

Answer (score 34):

Uma dica excelente para não ter problemas com charset é usar sempre a mesma codificação para:

1. Apache (arquivo httpd.conf ou .htaccess: `DefaultCharset UTF-8`)
2. Banco de Dados ( `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` )
3. HTML (`<meta charset="UTF-8">`)
4. Sistema de Arquivo (na hora de salvar o HTML em disco, verifique qual a codificação)