# Ajuda com caracteres especiais PHP e MSSql

Tags: php, sql

estou fazendo um formulário, e quando eu gravo a informação com caracteres especias, grava de boa... só que quando eu resgato a informação ela vem codificada... já usei , utf8_encode/decode e nada não sei se é no php ou no banco que tenho que mexer... detalhe, não tenho autonomia para mexer diretamente com o banco MSSql...

Um breve exemplo:

JOÃO PACIÊNCIA

quando eu uso: `$NOME =  utf8_encode($row['NOME']);` -> Ele traz o seguinte: "JO?O PACIÆNCIA"

quando eu uso: `$NOME =  utf8_decode($row['NOME']);` -> Ele traz o seguinte: "JO?O PACI?NCIA"

Quando eu uso: `$NOME =  ['NOME'];` -> Ele traz o seguinte: "JO?O PACI�NCIA"

Não sei se é com o BD ou na programação que eu mexo... 
Agradeço dês de já!

Comment: Seu banco é utf8 ou latin1? Seu PHP está configurado para usar utf8 ou iso-8859-1? Seu texto e confuso e os códigos postados também, por favor edite a questão e forneça um exemplo que possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Qual o driver do banco de dados está usando? mssql, sqlsrv, PDO, adodb?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vou ver um modo de edição que não fique tão confuso...

Comment: @Ursones leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 é provável que ajude

Comment: Outra coisa estranha é que o `ã` ficou como `?` e o `ê` ficou como `�`, para mim parece que tem dados misturados. Não sei dizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no seu banco de dado de, o collation tem que ser definido para utf8_geneal_ci ou algo relacionado, no seu php você tem que formatar para utf8 sem bom e na conexão do Banco de dados tem que instruir a cogitação de set nane utf8 ou algo relacionado no mssql e na hora de inserir ou ler a informação você não pode encodar ou decodar ou ele irá gerar conflito

Comment: É, eu não queria ter que mexer no Banco por ele ser antigo e ligado a um sistema mas não teve jeito... tive que mexer, obrigado pelo seu tempo e ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Além da formatação do texto, qual formatação da página você está usando? Tem que ver a formação da página e qual charset está definido no HTML. Um conflito de charset e formatação do HTML pode gerar esses tipos de erro.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Qual collation você está usando no banco?

Quando você adiciona as informações no banco você está fazendo o decode delas?
Ex: `$novoNome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);`

Answer (score -3):

Antes da instrução SQL coloca a seguinte expressão:

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Ele está usando o SQL Sever(mssql) e não o mysql. Existe algo similar no mssql(extensão antiga), [veja](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322421/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection) e no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.configuration.php)

Comment: ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');  seta ele

Answer (score -3):

Estava com um problema parece no cadastro de nomes com caracteres especiais e com apostrofo nos nomes, uso iso 8859-1 e utf8.

RESOLVI DESSA FORMA > $data['name'] = addslashes(utf8_encode($data['name']));

talvez ajude.