# Caracteres Especiais

Tags: php

Queria saber como eu posso fazer para usar caracteres especiais como "✞ ✟ ✠ ✡ ✢ ✣ ✤" , quando eu insiro um desses no meu banco de dados ele muda pra "?"

Alguma dica de como eu posso fazer isso ? não tenho ideia sobre isso ☹

Comment: Parece que o banco de dados ta convertendo eles automático para "?" estou usando var dump e eles estão sendo enviados direitos pro banco de dados

Comment: Qual encoding você está usando em sua base de dados? Tente utilizar mysql_real_escape_string() para dar o "encode" na string e após isso inserir ela na base de dados;

Comment: utf8 general ci

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122866/how-to-insert-special-character-in-mysql-via-php-and-display-on-html-page

Comment: Você tem certeza que o BD está convertendo pra `?`? Você tentou recuperar esses caracteres do BD, enviar ao cliente e tentar exibí-los? Se você consultar o BD através de um console ou outra ferramenta cuja **fonte** não dê suporte aos caracteres inseridos, ela vai **exibi-los** como `?` - embora continue armazenando o valor correto.

Comment: Sim esta convertendo

Comment: Quando eu envio um desses ate aparece esse erro no phpmyadmin Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x9C\x9F' for column 'tarefa' at row 1

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Esses como © ™ funcionam normal

Comment: Estranho acabei de testar aqui e funcionou tranquilo com seus caracteres. Já verificou o resultado da string sql antes de mandar ele executar?

Comment: Estou usando o wamp vou testar no servidor

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou, agora eu ate testei inserindo direto no phpmyadmin e mudou para "?"

Comment: Tente mudar o campo específico para colação utf-8

Comment: Se eu coloco eles no meu html eles aparecem então minha fonte da suporte pra eles...

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft mudei o campo que estava em padrão para utf8_general_ci e funcionou... agora não entendi o motivo

Comment: Bom... também não sei o motivo só analisando melhor mesmo para tentar descobrir, mas pelo menos resolveu então; Coloque a solução como resposta...

Comment: Isso aconteceu provavelmente porque a codificação dos arquivos PHP e do banco de dados era diferente (iso/latin1 e utf8). http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/problemas-com-charset-nunca-mais.html

Comment: Para usar estes caracteres você deve usar utf-8, veja isto deve lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635