# Array não é convertido para JSON

Tags: php, json

Trato algumas funções via PHP e no final devolvo ao cliente via AJAX as informações úteis. Tais informações estão contidas em um *array* que é convertido para JSON através do `json_encode()`. O problema é que é me enviada uma mensagem de erro com o seguinte:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Esse erro acontece porque o `json_encode()` não está me retornando nenhum *array*. Tenho minha variável:

```
$data = array(
    'command' => $command,
    'message' => $message
);
```

E o resultado do `var_dump` para o `json_encode()` é o seguinte (coloquei o código HTML para melhor visualização, executem-o):

```html
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
</pre>
```

O problema só acontece quando o valor da variável `$message` é vindo de um erro no banco de dados, se eu escrever qualquer coisa nela, o retorno é normal:

```html
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'{&quot;command&quot;:2,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Qualquer coisa&quot;}'</font> <i>(length=40)</i>
</pre>{"command":2,"message":"Qualquer coisa"}
```

Segue abaixo o `var_dump` de um exemplo de retorno da variável `$message`:

```html
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de &#39;&#39;NomeDeUsuario&#39;, &#39;$2a$05$Zx3hjrLOnWvNzZpRIhdcPecjreTjjaBkaYLrH7IRcfmn110et/92G&#39;,&#39; � la ligne 1'</font> <i>(length=121)</i>
</pre>
```

Percebam que isso é um erro no banco de dados. O erro em si não é relevante, eu mesmo o causei para testar o retorno de erros ao cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo erro `Erreur de syntaxe pr�s` com este caractere `�`, suponho que você esteja tentando passar uma string que usa `iso-8859-1`(latin) ao invés de `utf-8`, é provável que a sua página seja utf8, mas existam arquivos incluidos usando `iso-8859-1`

Para resolver mais facilmente, você pode converter a string para utf-8 primeiro:

```
$data = array(
    'command' => $command,
    'message' => $message
);

$data = utf8_encode($data);

echo json_encode($data);
```

### Detalhes:

O seu banco pode até estar em utf-8, mas pode ser que o modo que você fez a conexão pode estar trazendo e alguns arquivos podem estár usando `ANSI` com acentos do tipo `iso-8859-1`, leia este link pode lhe ajudar a padronizar o teu projeto:

- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

Comment: Perfeito! Jamais acharia que o problema tinha relação com isso. Tem algum meio de "converter" toda o banco para UTF-8, de modo que eu não precise tratar as respostas dessa forma? Tentei usar `ALTER DATABASE \`db\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` mas o erro continua com os acentos errados.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Mas você tem certeza que é o banco que não está em utf-8, ou é a conexão? Este código `ALTER DATABASE` é apenas uma situação, como eu disse no link que postei, tem várias coisas a se verificar. Por exemplo eu uso `utf8_unicode_ci`, mas outros usuário usa `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Acabei de recriar a tabela: http://i.imgur.com/zm8oUPk.png. Porém os acentos continuam errados. O que quer dizer com "conexão"? Adicionei um *header* UTF-8 na classe PHP que retorna os dados e mesmo assim nada.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida você usou `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` ou com PDO: `$conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`? Como eu disse amigo, não é só fazer uma coisa ou outra, tem que projetar seguindo todos os passos.

Comment: Falta de atenção, não vi o edit que fez. Muito obrigado, consegui converter tudo. :)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Sucesso pra ti!