# Inserção com caractéres fora do padrão

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quando eu insiro no banco de dados MySQL com PHP e PDO estão sendo inseridos caracteres estranhos e desordenados, o que poderá estar errado?

Segue uma imagem de uma tabela do banco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha página está com o parâmetro:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

E meu banco está com o seguinte `collation`:

```
utf8 - utf8_general_ci
```

O que acho estranho é que na minha aplicação está normal, haveria algum problema futuro, como `SELECT` dos dados?

Comment: A pagina e o PDO estão trabalhando em utf-8 tbm?

Comment: sim em minha página de visualização está normal, só gostaria de tirar a dúvida se isso pode complicar futuramente alguma coisa

Comment: Está resposta pode lhe ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: muito bom obrigado 0/

Comment: Uma informação para seu conhecimento: a `meta tag` do tipo `viewport` não tem relação alguma com os caracteres. A ideal para esse trabalho é a tag `<meta charset="tipo">`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente modificar a codificação do seu editor, no notepad++ por exemplo é possível fazer isso desta forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste a Codificação UTF-8 (sem BOM).