# Problemas com acentuação em .load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

O Site esta tudo certo, banco de dados, arquivos e meta tudo em utf-8, porem quando vou usar o

```
$("#aviso").load("inc/aviso.php");},1000);
```

Ele resulta esses caracteres ��, quando eu acesso o arquivo aviso.php ele esta com os acentos tudo certo.

Estou usando o utf-8 de padrão dês de o incio, não sei mais oque fazer.

Até usei

```
header ( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" ) ;

mysql_query ( "SET NAMES 'utf8'" ) ;

mysql_query ( "SET character_set_connection=utf8" ) ;

mysql_query ( "SET character_set_client=utf8" ) ;

mysql_query ( "SET character_set_results=utf8" ) ;
```

Porem não tive sucesso.

Comment: Esse problema já é antigo de muitos kk, conseguimos uma solução agora, mas lá na frente ele ira voltar kk

Comment: Verifica se vocês estão salvando os arquivos no OS como UTF-8, se estão usando Windows existe a possibilidade deles estarem sendo salvos em ISO, o que vai resultar em conflito ao ser lido pelo browser, ainda mais se vc estiver forçando um header que não reflete o encoding do arquivo sendo entregue.

Comment: Como dito ali em cima, O Site esta tudo certo, banco de dados, arquivos e meta tudo em utf-8,

Comment: Parece que o .load esta lendo errado.

Comment: O meta está certinho ? 
<meta charset="utf-8">, as vezes chamando dinamicamente da ruim ):

Comment: Estou dando um select no aviso.php apaguei tudo e digitei o mesmo texto teste que estava usando por o banco de dados, e os acentos pegarão, o problema esta no select do mysql

Comment: Usei um echo utf8_encode, pronto funcionou, não sei porque vou correr atras -.-'

Comment: Isto pode lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Answer (score 0):

Abra os arquivos no notepad++ e vá no botão do menu `formatar` e selecione a opção: `Codificação em UTF-8 (sem BOM)`

Comment: Sempre uso UTF-8 sem bom, não era esse o problema.