# Caracteres esquisitos

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, utf-8

Eu tenho uma base de dados com essa codificação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e também tenho o HTML com codificação UTF-8.

Mas por alguma razão os caracteres especiais aparecem desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu não consigo descobrir por qual razão isso acontece. Alguém me sabe explicar porque motivo os caracteres aparecem dessa maneira?

Comment: Como é que os dados da base-de-dados aparecem no html? Latin1 tem de ser convertido para UTF-8.

Comment: Relatado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser que seu arquivo **.HTML**, apesar de estar com **UTF-8** no código, tenha sido salvo com outra codificação.

Veja este este link para entender melhor: http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_resolver_problemas_de_acentua%C3%A7%C3%B5es_em_seu_site

Comment: Muito Obrigado Luciano resolveu o meu problema

Comment: Que bom! Já passei por esse problema um tempo atrás.

Comment: Isso resultou nos dados que já estavam inseridos na base de dados mas depois eu voltei a inserir mais e voltou ao mesmo. Sabe o que se passou?