# Problema com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou fazendo um bate-papo (chat) utilizando PHP e MySQL, e estou com problemas.

Acho que tem a ver com o fato do `php 5.5` não aceitar mais mysql, (agora é preciso usar mysqli) Pois bem, tenho dois arquivos:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Box</title>


<script>
function submitChat() {
    if(form1.uname.value == '' || form1.msg.value == '') {
      alert('ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY!!!');
      return;
  }
  var uname = form1.uname.value;
  var msg = form1.msg.value;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?uname='+uname+'&msg='+msg,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
Enter Your Chatname: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
Your Message: <br>
<textarea name="msg"></textarea><br>
<a href="#" onclick="submitChat()">Send</a><br><br>
<div id="chatlogs">
LOADING CHATLOGS PLEASE WAIT...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$con = mysqli_connect('XXX','XXX','XXX','XXX');

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO logs ('username','msg') VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");

while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
}
?>
```

Tenho um domínio onde está o código:
mundozoeira.com.br

Então podem ir lá para ver o comportamento.

Comment: Qual é o problema? @Renan

Comment: O chat simplesmente não funciona. mando a mensagem e nada acontece. quer dizer, a frase "LOADING CHATLOGS PLEASE WAIT..." desaparece, ela é substituída usando innerHTML. Não faço ideia do que seja...

Comment: Pode ser um erro no mysql database?

Comment: Mano, depois da sua conexão coloca esse código. `if ( $con ->connect_errno )
 {
  printf("Erro na Conexão: %s\n", $con ->connect_error);
  exit();
 }`

Comment: já botei. nada aconteceu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é na sua *query*, no mysql não usamos apostrofo (`'`) na onde fazemos referencias as colunas, o correto é:

```
INSERT INTO logs (`username`,`msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')
```

Pode ser um erro de conexão com o mysql, tente editar o arquivo para algo como:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$uname = empty($_REQUEST['uname']) ? NULL : $_REQUEST['uname'];
$msg = empty($_REQUEST['msg']) ? NULL : $_REQUEST['msg'];

if (NULL === $uname || NULL === $msg) {
    echo 'Faltam dados';
    exit;
}

$con = mysqli_connect('XXX','XXX','XXX','XXX');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$resultado = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO logs (`username`, `msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");

if ($resultado === false) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit;
}

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");

if ($result1 === false) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit;
}

while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Pra usar o caractere acento grave nas *queries mysql*, use a tecla ao lado do numero 1 e acima do tab sem usar o <kbd>Shift</kbd>, como na imagem:

[image: Teclado Abnt]

### Outros possíveis problemas

1. Short open tags

   Troque `<?` por `<?php`

   Note que para usar `<?` você necessita estar com isto habilitado no php.ini, ou igual a `1`:

   ```
   short_open_tag=1
   ```

   Note também que a partir do PHP5.4 isto funciona sem `short_open_tag`:

   ```
   <?='Teste'?>
   ```

   Mas isto não funcionará:

   ```
   <?
   echo 'Test';
   ?>
   ```
2. Erro na codificação do arquivo

   Se você salvar o arquivo com codificações diferentes do **ANSI** e do **UTF-8 sem BOM** ou outro tipo de codificação, isto pode causar a falha na execução do PHP.

   Para corrigir, sempre salve o arquivo como **ANSI** ou **UTF-8 sem BOM** (no caso eu prefiro o utf8), para isso é necessário usar um editor avançado como o SublimeText ou o Notepad++, veja:

   Usando notepad++:

   [image: utf8 sem boom notepad++]

   Usando Sublime Text:

   [image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]

   Mais detalhes em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635
3. Servidor Apache sem o PHP instalado, você pode estar usando o servidor Apache sem PHP.

   - Pra instalar o Wamp (Window+Apache+Mysql+php) você pode usar pacotes prontos como:

     - Wamp: http://www.wampserver.com/en/
     - Xampp: https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html
   - Pra instalar no Ubuntu ou debian use o `apt` no terminal, execute os seguintes comandos:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install apache2
     sudo apt-get install php5
     sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.0
     sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
     sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
     ```

Comment: TOPPP!!!! Sua resposta.