# Charset Mysql e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Minha tabela no mysql está com a formatação UTF-8 e aparecendo todas as acentuações corretamente, porém quando eu faço a requisição com o PHP e exibo os dados eles não aparecem com o formato UTF-8.

p.s: minha pagina já esta com o meta para utf-8.

vocês sabem o que pode estar acarretando este problema?

Comment: Tive problemas que talvez sejam os seus, aqui esta o link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824163/json-return-null-or-char-code

Comment: Acredito que está resposta deve resolver o problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Você criou os registros na tabela manualmente?

Answer (score 3):

Como é feita sua conexão, Mysql Conect, Mysqli, PDO?

Acho que essa seria a solução:

```
@mysql_query("SET NAME 'utf8'");
@mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
@mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
@mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
```

PDO:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);
$db-> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Mysqli:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Verifica conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Falha ao fazer conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Set utf8
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

CODIGNITER:

Favor conferir se o config.php e database.php estão assim

config.php

```
`$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'
```

database.php:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
```

e

```
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

UFT-8 NA REQUISIÇÂO AJAX:

```
.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET", 
        url: url, 
        contentType: "charset=utf-8", 
        success: function(data)
            { 
                $(".container").html(data);
            }
});
```

HEADER:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Certifique-se de que todos os seus arquivos são salvos como UTF-8 (UTF-8 ou w.o BOM). Configure a formatação na sua IDE.

Comment: é conexao via PDO e estou usando o Codeigniter! você sabe como arrumar isso no framework?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly -> Editei a resposta.

Comment: Já está tudo do jeito que você comentou; quando eu faço a consulta no banco de dados para exibir no painel de admin a formatação utf-8 aparece normalmente, porém quando eu faço uma requisição no index (por exemplo) a formatação não funciona mesmo o meta charset já estando definido.

Comment: Posta o código, fica mais fácil pra te ajudar. Vou editar novamente a resposta.