# strtoupper() com acentos

Tags: php, funções, acentuação

A função `strtoupper()` do PHP não esta transformando as letras com acento em maiúsculo, veja o exemplo:

```
echo strtoupper("virá"); // retorna VIRá
```

Tem alguma função nativa que resolve esse problema?

Comment: echo mb_strtoupper("virá",'UTF-8');

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar a sua contraparte, [mb_strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) que vai tratar de unicode:

```
$encoding = mb_internal_encoding(); // ou UTF-8, ISO-8859-1...
echo mb_strtoupper("virá", $encoding); // retorna VIRÁ
```

ou

```
$encoding = 'UTF-8'; // ou ISO-8859-1...
mb_convert_case('virá', MB_CASE_UPPER, $encoding);
```

Isso se dá porque funções da mb_* operarão nas strings com base em suas propriedades Unicode. Caracteres acentuados não são "formações" regulares, e sim multibytes. É por isso que se você usa strlen("virá") o resultado será 5 caracteres, ao invés de 4 (como você esperava).

### Sobre encoding escolhido

Desde que não podemos adivinhar em que encoding em que se salva os arquivos e em que encoding se usa no output, não se pode aqui informar o correto. Você deverá descobrir isso. O melhor conselho é que se salve os arquivos fontes em UTF-8 (todo editor tem essa opção) e no output force a saída em UTF-8, usando tag `<meta charset="SEU-ENCODING">`

Comment: com a tag meta em utf-8 fica "VIRá" e sem a tag só php com echo virá fica "VIRÃ¡"

Comment: Opa agora sim rolou, obrigado!!

Comment: @SneepSNinjA não podemos adicinhar em que encoding você salva seus arquivos e em que encoding você usa no output. Você deverá descobrir isso. O melhor conselho é que você salva seus arquivos fontes em UTF-8 (todo editor tem essa opção) e no output force a saída em UTF-8, usando tag <meta charset="SE-ENCODING">

Answer (score 13):

### MB_STRTOUPPER

`mb_strtoupper('virá', 'UTF-8');`

Ou

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_strtoupper('virá');
```

Comment: Testei e não funcionou...

Comment: Qual seu charset ?

Comment: Pois é, faltou colocar essa informação que tem que informar o encoding..

Comment: sim precisa passar esse encoding, agora funcionou o @felipsmartins atualizou a resposta dele também

Comment: Beleza. Eu não coloquei de primeira porquê eu testei aqui antes numa página minha sem passar Encoding e foi de boa.

Answer (score 1):

Além de ter que lidar com acentuação da função `strtoupper` tive também que fazer um *cast* com os dados que vinham do banco, o código ficou assim.

```
mb_strtoupper(utf8_encode($variavel_do_banco['nome_coluna_banco']));
```

Comment: Vale como observação. (logo você pode comentar em qualquer postagem, só faltam alguns pontinhos de reputação). Talvez não seja a solução mais adequada, pois isso aconteceu por causa do banco configurado de maneira incompatível. Sugeriria trabalhar sempre na mesma codificação, tanto no editor de código quanto no DB e serviço HTTP

Comment: @Bacco sobre esse erro na codificação de caracteres, encontrei a solução [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: Como comentei, é uma solução paliativa nesse contexto. O encode e o decode são válidos para compatibilizar dois sistemas diferentes, mas numa aplicação só, em teoria, nunca deveriam ser usados (afinal, a aplicação deveria trabalhar com o mesmo encoding em todas as camadas). Em outras palavras, de fato isso que você falou pode corrigir os sintomas, mas a sugestão é sempre tentar resolver na origem.

Answer (score 0):

Se usar ISO-8859-1

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

echo mb_strtoupper("maçãs são boas", 'ISO-8859-1');
```