# Caracteres com acento é considerado como dois caracteres

Tags: php

Caracteres com acento são considerados como dois(imagino que seja a quantidade de bytes), como posso corrigir isso ??

```
$t = "á";
if(strlen($t) == 1){
    echo "UM CARACTER";
}
if(strlen($t) == 2){
    echo "DOIS CARACTER";
}
if(strlen($t) == 3){
    echo "TRES CARACTER";
}
```

Outro problema que estou enfrentando é `$string{0}` não conseguir identificar os acentos.

```
$text = "á25";

echo $text{0}."<br>"; //retorna �
echo $text{1}."<br>"; //retorna �
echo $text{2}."<br>"; //retorna 2
echo $text{3}."<br>"; //retorna 5
```

E colocando em ISO-8859-1 fica

```
$text = "á25";

echo $text{0}."<br>"; //retorna Ã
echo $text{1}."<br>"; //retorna ¡
echo $text{2}."<br>"; //retorna 2
echo $text{3}."<br>"; //retorna 5
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84100/strtoupper-com-acentos/84104

Comment: Lucas essa edição não seria um novo problema, diferente do relatado anteriormente?

Comment: Mais ou menos, o problema ainda tem a ver com os caracteres com acento, caso ache melhor eu abro uma nova pergunta :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso depende da codificação como você mesmo notou. O UTF-8, que é o mais comum, varia de 1 byte (sendo 7 bits uteis) até 4 bytes (sendo 21 bits uteis). Todo o ASCII usa apenas 7 bits, ou seja o bit mais significante dele é sempre zero (0xxxxxxx) para completar um byte.

Agora caracteres acentuados estão além do ASCII, não existe nele. Por essa razão existem outras codificações para suportar acentos. O UTF-8 utiliza mais de um byte para isso, já o ISO-8859-1, também conhecido como Latin 1, ainda continua utilizando um byte, porém usando os 8 bits.

Quando você usa `á` você tem que dizer o que é isso, na maioria dos casos será usado UTF-8, que por sua vez utilizará 2 bytes.

---

Uma solução é utilizar:

```
mb_strlen('á', 'UTF-8');
// = 1
```

*É importante definir o segundo parâmetro, porque o comportamento pode ser alterado até mesmo pelo [mbstring.func_overload](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.overload.php).*

Se quiser cortar um trecho pode utilizar:

```
mb_substr('á25', 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
// = á
```

Se quiser criar uma array com os valores multi-bytes:

```
preg_split('//u', 'á25', null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// = array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "á" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "5" }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Você está correto, [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) retorna o número de bytes. Para retornar o número de caracteres, use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php) ou [`iconv_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iconv-strlen.php):

```
$t = "à";
print strlen($t); // 2
print mb_strlen($t); // 1
print iconv_strlen($t); // 1
```

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta, pode complementar sua resposta ?? :D

Answer (score 0):

A função `strlen()` funciona bem para iso-8859-1 (texto sem acentuação).
`stlen()` não conta o número de caracteres e sim o numero de bytes.

Quando o texto possui acentuação (enconde multibite) use `mb_strlen()` que retorna a quantidade de caracteres.

A função `mb_strlen()` permite definir um parâmetro chamado `encoding`.

```
$t = "á";
tam  = mb_strlen($t, 'utf8');
echo $tam;//resultado 1
```

[**teste aqui**](https://repl.it/Jo7o/0)

Letras acentuadas é um problema, vejam esse artigo  [usar acentos em uma mensagem SMS](https://blogdoiphone.com/2011/04/voce-sabia-acentos-sms/)

Comment: O que estaria errado para o -1? 0-0