# Problema com a acentuação da função de escrever o número por extenso PHP

Tags: php, acentuação

Boa tarde pessoal, to com um problema na função "NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT" no PHP, ela serve para escrever o numero por extenso, porém mesmo definindo o tipo de linguagem PT_BR, ela ta imprimindo os acentos por exemplo do número três; bugado.
Já verifiquei o encoding do banco e do arquivo, ta tudo em UTF-8 certinho, mais os acentos imprimem todos com erro.

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('PT_BR', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT); //Define a Função do PHP que escreve por extenso

$valorextenso=$formatter->format($line7->valorbruto); //Chama a Função do PHP que escreve por extenso
                
$valorextenso=strtoupper($valorextenso);
$valor=number_format($line7->valorbruto, 2, ',', '.');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é o `strtoupper($valorextenso)`, você deve usar `mb_strtoupper($valorextenso, 'UTF-8')`, ao invés disso. O `strtoupper` não suporta UTF-8.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta deveria ser fechada por ser duplicada desta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84100/strtoupper-com-acentos.