# Problema de acentuação no Ubuntu 14.04 x64 DigitalOcean

Tags: mysql, linux, servidor

estou com um problema de acentuação no meu Servidor na Nuvem que estou usando (Ubuntu 14.04 x64), onde, eu tento dar a seguinte linha de comando (no prompt do linux), usando o Putty, porém, quando dou um refresh na URL nao vem os acentos.

Exemplo:

Dentro do `putty`, no meu *mysql* estou dando o seguinte comando:

```
insert into convenio (nome) values('Téste');
```

repare que tem um acenso na letra E.

quando eu rodo esse comando, no browser aparece para mim a seguinte forma:

```
"nome":"TÃ©ste"
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: qual o encoding do banco de dados no seu servidor? provavelmente esse é o problema.

Comment: Problema de `locale`. No servidor você precisa instalar o pt_BR.ISO-8859-1. Talvez já esteja instalado, neste caso você só precisa setar como padrão. Se não me engano, como padrão sempre está utf-8. [estas intruções devem resolver](http://elcio.com.br/configurando-o-locale-no-ubuntu/)

Comment: O problema não tem haver com o servidor, o seu problema é na hora de passar os dados pra resposta no navegador, o servidor neste caso é irrelevante pra duvida, se pesquisar aqui no SOpt vai notar que já existe resposta pra este problema, sem querer ofender, veja esta minha resposta deve lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: @georgesilva converti em comentário a tua resposta. Se quiseres dar uma resposta mais completa, inclusive juntando conteúdo desse link aqui (referenciando) seria o ideal. Se esse link falhar um dia a resposta fica incompleta.