# LocalStorage não guarda nomes com acento?

Tags: html5, ionic, localstorage

Minha app em ionic guarda os dados do usuário, como nome, em localStorage.
Fui fazer um teste, me loguei com o nome da minha esposa, Flávia, porém, quando olhei no console na aba Resources, o campo nome estava null e o id tinha o id dela de usuário. Fui no banco a alterei o nome dela, tirei o acento da letra a. Voltei, me loguei e o nome dela apareceu!
Vocês sabem se o localStorage permite guardar nomes com acento?
Se não, como devo fazer?

Parte do index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
```

Meu login.html:

```
<ion-view title="Login" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
        <ion-list>
            <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="usuario.email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="password" ng-model="usuario.senha" placeholder="Senha">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
            <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="logar(usuario)">Entrar</button>
            <!--<a href="#/salas" class="button button-stable button-block ">Entrar</a> -->
            <a href="#/cadastroCep" class="button button-stable button-block ">Cadastre-se</a>
            <div align="center">{{msgErro}}</div>
            </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Meu controller.js

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, $location, $window) {

$scope.usuario = {
    email: "",
    senha: ""
}

$scope.msgErro = '';

$scope.msgExiste = '';

$scope.logar = function (usuario) {

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/login.php", usuario).success(function (response){

        if(response == ''){
            $location.path('/page10');
            $scope.msgErro = "E-mail ou senha inválido";

        }else if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    $window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuario", response.idUsuario);
                    $window.localStorage.setItem("idCep", response.idCep);
                    $window.localStorage.setItem("nome", response.nome);
                    $location.path('/salas');
                } else {
                    console.log("Desculpe, mas o navegador nao possui suporte a Web Storage.");
                }
      })
   }
})
```

Print do console:
[image: console]

Comment: login.html está salvo como utf8-without-bom pelo seu editor de texto (notepad++ ou sublimetext por exemplo)?

Comment: Depois dessa linha, `}else if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {` , adicione isso `console.log("Nome: "+response.nome);` . Teste usando um nome com acentuação e veja no console do browser o que aparece. No chrome, pressione `Ctr+Shift+I`

Comment: É @DanielOmine, pareceu isso no console:
Nome: null

Agora não entendi o pq ele não está pegando o nome.

Comment: Suspeitei desde o princípio.. Pode ser o script na página  `ww/php/login.php ` que esteja retornando errado. Verifique o que há de errado nesse script pois aparentemente não há erro no javascript que apresentou na pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente @DanielOmine, coloquei um print_r no no fim do login.php pra ver como os dados estão vindo e veja só como está o nome:

Array
(
    [idUsuario] => 45
    [idCep] => 66
    [tipoUsuario] => C
    [nome] => Fl�via Schneider
    [email] => flav.sch@terra.com.br
)

Como posso corrigir isso no php?

Comment: configure o encode do ambiente do php. há vários tópicos aqui sobre o assunto. É um assunto meio complicado e extenso para explicar nos comentários. Verifique qual o charset do banco de dados e configure o php de acordo com o charset do banco., basicamente.

Comment: Não, o charset do banco é utf8, mas pelo que vi tenho que fazer tratamento da variável nome no php mesmo

Comment: então blz, não posso afirmar e dizer "faça X, faça Y", mas acho que pode apenas adicionar o header no arquivo php. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`. Verifique também se o editor de textos que usou para editar o arquivo PHP está como `utf-8 without bom`. Também verifique o que retorna a função `echo mb_internal_encoding(); exit;`. Mas são palpites somente. Como disse, não há como resolver sem saber como realmente está todo o ambiente. Note que mesmo o banco configurado como utf8, os dados podem estar sendo gravados erroneamente com outro charset, ou seja, corrompidos.

Answer (score 1):

Isto ocorre porque o arquivo `www/php/login.php` está vindo sem acentos

> Eu sempre digo pra você postar o código que possa ser reproduzido, mas parece que você sempre falha nisto, mais uma vez por favor para evitar dificuldades em te ajudar siga as dicas deste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Não sei como esta o seu PHP, mas para que os acentos funcionem você tem que fazer como nesta resposta:

- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

  - Salve todos documentos PHP e HTML com as mesma codificação *utf8 sem BOM* ou *ANSI* (não use ANSI se seu banco for utf8)
  - Se for utf8 você deve abrir a conexão assim (no teu login.php) se for usar PDO:

    ```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BANCO;charset=utf-8', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
    $conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');//Define o charset como UTF-8
    ```

    ou assim se for usar mysqli:

    ```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

    if (false === $mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
        printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', $mysqli->error);
    }
    ```

> Não use a API antiga do mysql para PHP (aquelas que começam com `mysql_`):
>
> - [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

Answer (score -1):

Parece ser a codificação do seu arquivo. Na parte `<head>` do seu index.html adicione esta linha:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Não, eu tenho esse meta charset no código.

Comment: @GustavoSevero você poderia colocar o trecho do código onde o erro ocorre no Codepen?

Comment: Acabei de postar os códigos aqui.
OBS: Não sei mexer no codeopen kkkkk

Comment: Só uma nota @SCOFIELD não fui eu quem negativou, ando até evitando de fazer isso. Realmente a pergunta está bem vaga, quando for assim é preferível fechar a pergunta até que ela apresente os dados mínimos para poder ser respondível, eu só consegui entender o problema por causa de um comentário lá na pergunta.