# UTF8 só funciona só no mysql ou só na página

Tags: php, mysql

Em coon.php que serve como conexão para o meu banco de dados, se eu adicionar esse codigo:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

o nome fica como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu tirar fica como nessa imagem.. Usando essa no banco de dados fica "BraganÃ§Ã£o" em vez de "Braganção" ae o problema é, quando eu vou carregar mais coisas via json/ajax etc... ele vai pegar "BraganÃ§Ã£o" e não "braganção"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

objetivo: fazer o nome ficar utf8 tanto na página tanto no banco de dados para sempre puxar o nome correto

Comment: Na pagina tem o meta com o utf-8¶

Comment: @rray sim  tanto esse <meta charset="utf-8"> tanto <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Seu arquivo foi salvo como utf-without BOM? Pode garantir os dados gravados estao com o encode certo?

Comment: @rray utf-without??, a estrutura no phpadmin está em utf8_general_ci

Comment: Quando eu puxo do banco ele far isso  $sql = "ALTER DATABASE portfolio CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci";

Comment: o arquivo php, veja no notepad++  se ele est[a como utf-8 without bom

Comment: @rray como eu vejo isso me explica fazendo o favor ;)

Comment: Clica no menu enconding que ja aparece ou no canto inferior direito

Comment: @rray está em UTF8 - (SEM BOM)

Comment: @rray em qual encode eu coloco?

Comment: Esta certo assim.

Comment: @rray e agora :( ???

Comment: Fraciona o projeto em partes pra encontrar o problema. Cria um novo arquivo, limpo e com charset correto, faz a conexão e manda imprimir os dados com echo. No início do arquivo php defina: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); poste o resultado.

Comment: Coloque o trecho de código que mostra os caracteres acima, aparentemente você está fazendo dupla conversão.

Comment: Esta pergunta [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8) é diferente, mas a resposta lá explica como resolver o problema passo-a-passo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode especificar a codificação do documento logo após iniciar a tag

```
 <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html charset='utf-8'");
 ?>
```

E logo após só incluir a estrutura que já estava utilizando

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Comment: colocar isso no coon.php?

Comment: mesmo colocando isso, quando aperto no botão carregar que ele vai puxar mais coisas do banco, fica aparecendo BraganÃ§Ã£o