# Recolha de Dados do banco de dados erro de acentuação

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, eu tenho uma query que me tira os dados de uma tabela do banco de dados e armazena numa array, contudo, os dados no banco de dados têm acentos.

Quando vou a imprimir na tela os dados com

```
<?php echo $array["nome"]; ?>
```

O apresentado fica com erros de acentuação, onde tem acentuação fica com pontos de interrogação pretos.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/91)

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
<?php echo utf8_encode($array["nome"]); ?>
```

ou:

```
<?php echo utf8_decode($array["nome"]); ?>
```

Veja a documentação em:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php