# Resultados com acentos no PHP viram Símbolos

Tags: php

> Quero deixar claro que pesquisei no fórum e em muitos outros lugares sobre isso, nenhum solucionou meu problema, então não venham marcar como duplicado pois acredito que meu problema seja especifico.

**A situação é a seguinte**, tenho um sistema que faz a consulta de CNPJ e retorna os dados da empresa, porém quando ele retorna os dados, os acentos voltam nesse modo `�`.

### **Informações**

A página obviamente está em `.php` mas contém HTML, o html está com a meta `<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`.

### **O que tentei**

```
 ini_set("Content-Type: text/html; charset=",true);
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8');
 <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
```

Nenhum funcionou e o estranho é que parte do PHP mostra os acentos normalmente e o html inteiro mostra os acentos normais.O problema mesmo é quando ele vai retornar os resultados, é só lá que os acentos viram `�`.

Código está assim

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-Language" content="pt-br">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Dpev78tlrZLwv3LWGgVXA9_AvLw3JksSJyvYYnBNMvk" />
    <title>Barie Toner - Recarga de Toner e Cartuchos, Manutenção de Impressoras em São Bernardo</title>
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
    <meta content="Recarga de Toner e Cartuchos em São Bernardo, Manutenção de Impressoras em SBC, São Bernardo, Recarga de Cartuchos e Toners HP, LexMark, Brother, Epson, Brother e Copiadoras. Toners Compatíveis..." name="description" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="Copyright" content="(c) 2016 Barie Toner Recarga de Toner e Cartuchos" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abrir(URL) {

            var width = 466;
            var height = 580;

            var left = 99;
            var top = 99;

            window.open(URL, 'janela', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');
        }
    </script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/ICON.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,600,500,300,200,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/topbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- shell -->
    <div class="shell">
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- header -->
            <header id="header">
                <!-- aparecer no desktop -->
                <div class="mobile-hide">
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Recarga de Toner e Cartuchos, Manutenção de Impressoras</a></h1></div>
                <!-- aparecer no mobile -->
                <div class="mobile">
                    <div class="desktop-hide">
                        <h1 class="logomobile"><a href="#">Recarga de Toner e Cartuchos, Manutenção de Impressoras</a></h1></div>
                </div>
                <!-- search -->
                <div class="search">
                    <form action="resultado.php" id="cse-search-box">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="001732308738676474369:mki_bote1mm" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
                        <input "text" name="q" size="31" class="field" value="Pesquise aqui" title="Pesquise aqui" />
                        <input type="submit" name="sa" class="search-btn" value="" />
                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- end of search -->
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </header>
            <!-- end of header -->
            <!-- navigaation -->
            <nav id="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Abrir Menu<span></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Consultar Endereço</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cfdw.php">Consultar CEP</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="ndsa.php">Consultar CNPJ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="razda.php">Consultar Razão Social</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </nav>
            <!-- end of navigation -->
            <!-- main -->
            <div class="main">

                <div class="featured">
                <?php
                ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8');
                require('funcoes.php');

                $cnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
                $captcha = $_POST['CAPTCHA'];

                // pega html resposta da receita
                $getHtmlCNPJ = getHtmlCNPJ($cnpj, $captcha);

                if($getHtmlCNPJ)
                {
                    // volova os dados em um array
                    $campos = parseHtmlCNPJ($getHtmlCNPJ);

                    echo "mostra os resultados";
                }
                ?>
                </div>

                <!-- end of main -->
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

                <!-- footer -->
                <div id="footer">
                    <div class="footer-nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Ínicio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                            <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                            <li><a href="area-de-cobertura.html">Cobertura</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                            </br>
                            <li>diretoria@barietoner.com.br | vendas@barietoner.com.br | (11) 2922-5072</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="copy">
                        <a href="skype:diretoria@barietoner.com.br?chat"><img src="css/images/skype.png"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:abrir('https://tawk.to/c6fe2e15a65eee77616fd7836828c5b00f470407/popout/default/?$_tawk_popout=true&$_tawk_sk=56dd81082445fbd60e8104b7&$_tawk_tk=d9297f446fdd74f9eaf318bc1c43190e&v=458');"><img src="css/images/suporte.png"></a>
                        <a href="mailto:suporte@barietoner.com.br"><img src="css/images/email.png"></a>
                        <a href="contato.html"><img src="css/images/telefone.png"></a>
                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of footer -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of container -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of shell -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of wrapper -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Não sei mais o que fazer, tudo que faço retorna sempre no mesmo erro.*

Comment: Tentou utilizar utf8_decode($string); ?
Outra coisa, o arquivo que você esta criando, esta em qual encoding?

Comment: Esse eu ainda não tentei, vou tentar e te aviso e já testei todos os encoding permitidos, eu uso o Sublime Text e a variação dele é grande, mas mesmo assim, sem nenhum resultado.

Comment: Tente utilizar utf8_encode ($conteudo) ou  utf8_decode ($conteudo)

Comment: @FleuquerLima ele funciona com o echo normal?

Comment: Olhou isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/91?

Comment: sim, basta utilizar assim:  echo utf8_encode($conteudo);

Comment: Sim @rray, porém não me ajudou em nada infelizmente.

Comment: Notei que no seu html tem os dois charsets, deixe apenas um, sugiro o utf-8

Comment: Qual *charset*, *collation* você esta usando no banco? se o banco não da suporte a acento, o erro vem de la.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, o problema foi resolvido utilizando `utf8_encode($conteudo);`, bem simples alias, nem precisava de ter mudado tanta coisa haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problema solucionado** da seguinte forma:

Acredito que pelo uso de `echo` o resultado sairia com uma codificação diferente da página, então me indicaram usar a tag `utf8_decode($string);` para codificar para UTF8, echo por echo e realmente funcionou.

### **O código estava:**

```
            <?php
            ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8');
            require('funcoes.php');

            $cnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
            $captcha = $_POST['CAPTCHA'];

            // pega html resposta da receita
            $getHtmlCNPJ = getHtmlCNPJ($cnpj, $captcha);

            if($getHtmlCNPJ)
            {
                // volova os dados em um array
                $campos = parseHtmlCNPJ($getHtmlCNPJ);

                echo "mostra os resultados";
            }
            ?>
```

**Fiz a simples alteração:**

```
            $cnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
            $captcha = $_POST['CAPTCHA'];

            // pega html resposta da receita
            $getHtmlCNPJ = getHtmlCNPJ($cnpj, $captcha);

            if($getHtmlCNPJ)
            {
                // volova os dados em um array
                $campos = parseHtmlCNPJ($getHtmlCNPJ);

            echo utf8_encode(mostra os resultados);
            }
            ?>
```

**E o problema foi resolvido.**

Comment: utf8_decode ou utf8_encode?