# Caracteres desconhecidos em data PHP

Tags: php, data

Estou tento um problema com caracteres desconhecidos na data de um site, já coloquei todos os parâmetros que acreditava sanar o problema, mas continua a acontecer.

"SÁBADO, 16 DE ABRIL DE 2016" está saindo "S?BADO, 16 DE ABRIL DE 2016"

Como posso corrigir isto? Obrigado

`<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
    echo mb_strtoupper(strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today')), 'UTF-8'); 
?>`

Comment: Provavelmente sua página não está em UTF-8, mas você está pedindo este encoding no mb_strtoupper. Troque o `'UTF-8'` por `'ISO-8859-1'` para testar.

Comment: @Bacco, valeu! Tenho a página definida com o <meta charset="UTF-8"/>. Fiz esta alteração que você falou e a falha continua, porém o caractere mudou, ficando "S�BADO". Peço no mb_strtoupper porque preciso mesmo tudo em maiúsculo,  mas fiz um teste e retirei o mb_strtoloupper e também dá a falha de caracteres em minusculas.

Comment: @TotalShockPubli Em que codificação está salvo seu arquivo que está este `script`?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: @TotalShockPubli remova o UTF-8 completamente e deixe só `mb_strtoupper(strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today')));` pra ver se não é duplo encoding

Comment: @bacco, fiz com você indicou e continuou a falha de caractere. (usei o seu código mesmo). Estranho isto. tanto em localhost como no servidor da a mesma falha. O que será? Se vc usar este codigo, voce vê a falha no seu PC colega? Obrigado

Comment: @bacco Alguma saída para esta falha pessoal? obrigado

Comment: @TotalShockPubli eu tenho quase certeza que é alguma bobeirinha, mas é complicado ajudar no contexto atual. Minha sugestão seria você tirar o `mb_strtoupper` por enquanto, e começar com uma página vazia sem locale nem nada. Só com isso: `echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today')), 'UTF-8');` - Mais nadinha na página de testes. Aí se não funcionar corretamente, você acrescenta apenas um HTML básico em torno da função, com `<meta charset="UTF-8">` pra ver se resolve. Aí vamos incrementando.

Comment: @baco, estou um questão aqui colega, como posso fazer para chamar uma data anterior que contenha o caractere estranho? tipo assim, eu conseguia ver os caracteres estranhos em sábado ou terça, (Á) e (Ç) chamando today, nestes dias, ou yesterday no dia anterior, mas hoje é quinta e se chamar today e yestarday pego sexta e quarta que nao apresentam caracteres entranhos, tem alguma forma de chamar sabado e terça, sendo hoje quinta?