# SQL query retorna �

Tags: php, sql

tenho uma tabela para a query enviar para lá as informações, e aparece "�" em vez de letras com acentos. No html já estou a usar `<meta charset="UTF-8">` falta algo? é a primeira vez que me acontece isto.

Comment: A resposta nesta pergunta deve lhe ajudar [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: Nesse post diz para eu gravar sempre sem o BOM, eu gravo e não tem problema, os dados são inseridos com os acentos todos corretamente, o problema é que se eu não inserir com o PHP, e inserir somento no phpmyadmin, quando tento ver os dados por PHP vem esses caracteres.

Comment: Nesse poste que linkei (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635) fala muito mais do que BOM, fala de tudo, desde como conectar, como salvar e como definir o header ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua conexão com o banco de dados, você precisa definir o charset.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

E verifique também se sua base está em utf-8

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```