# Meu json retorna caracter inválido no PHP

Tags: php, json

Preciso montar um `JSON`, no `PHP`, para retornar dados para o AngularJS, mas um dos dados do object do `JSON` está vindo com a letra "á" com outro caractere. Como posso corrigir isso?
OBS: O nome está com acento no BD, pois foi inserida no BD com acento. O BD está configurado com utf8-bin.

Meu php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include_once("conPDO.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$idUsuario = $_GET['idUsuario'];

$pegaUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario=:idUsuario");
$pegaUsuario->bindValue(":idUsuario", $idUsuario);
$pegaUsuario->execute();

$return = array();

while ($linha=$pegaUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return, $linha);
}
print_r($return[0]);
//echo json_encode($return[0]);
```

?>

E vejam como o object json aparece no console, vejam o nome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8). Tente tudo da resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, incluindo o `exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`

Comment: Já resolvido o problema?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, estou usando utf8-bin, no banco de dados, então o banco aceita letras com acento.
Só não entendo o porque esse json, "destorce" a letra "á".

Comment: Por que faltou o `$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');` como eu já disse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outra solução, caso a citada anteriormente não funcione, é você percorrer o objeto que transformar seus atributos em `UTF8`:

```
for(x in objeto){
  objeto[x] = utf8_encode(objeto[x]);
}
```

## Editado

Solução:

```
while ($linha=$pegaUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $linha['nome'] = utf8_encode($linha['nome']); 
    array_push($return, $linha);
}
```

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas dai "á", vira "?"

Comment: tente utilizar essa outra função: mb_convert_encoding(objeto[x], "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding(objeto[x], "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));

Comment: Caso não funcione, antes do print do json, de um echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">', isso irá resolver

Comment: retornou isso no console:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">Array
(
    [idUsuario] => 3
    [idCep] => 3
    [tipoUsuario] => C
    [nome] => Fl�via Schneider
    [usuario] => 
)

Comment: Acredito que is dados não apareçam na tela, no html, pq o nome está com acento, pois se testo com nome sem acento, dai os dados aparecem na tela, entende?

Comment: na hora de imprimir o json, testou usar echo json_encode($objeto);die;?

Comment: Acabei de tentar Julyano, mas não acontece nada... Não aparece os dados na tela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41616/discussion-between-julyano-felipe-and-gustavosevero).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar varias funções do php para converter seu caractere em um caracter html, ansii etc use esta função antes de salvar no banco de dados

```
htmlentities($suaString)
```

isto irá converter seu caracter em um caracter `&aacute;`
Há varios fatores que podem está gerándo este erro de charcode 
verifique se seu arquivo está em utf-8 recomendo essa formatação, se há um include de outro verifique se ele também está formatado
use a meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` no html use também o header no php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

Remomendo trabalhar com o notpad++ você pode [baixa-lo aqui](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: htmlentities? Que eu saiba só se usa htmlentities quando usamos HTML e PHP, mas no caso, estou trabalhando com angularJS.

Comment: você colocou em  suas tags php e json

Answer (score 0):

Como mais uma alternativa, e diminuindo algumas linhas de código, utilize o [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php) para já obter um `array` contendo os elementos das linhas retornadas no `sql` e a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para aplicar o [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) em todos os elementos do `array`:

```
$return = $pegaUsuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$encoded = array_map("utf8_encode", $return);

var_dump(json_encode($encoded, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```