# Problemas com caracteres especiais html5 bootstrap

Tags: html, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou com problemas no meu html, a página não reconhece os caracteres especiais.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    <title>Verde</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funcoes/mrsJsonUtil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/funcoes/dbtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/funcoes/funcoes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom_dialogs/bootbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jsonservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bd_web.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/funcoes/monta_selects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/funcoes/mrsJsonUtil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="images/webcam/jquery.webcam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Especifico de cada cadastro-->
    <script src="js/cadastro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body> 
    <div id="divMenu"></div>
    <div class="container">        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Cadastro de Agente

                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="formCadastro" role="form"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <div id="divFoto"></div>
                                    <img id="imgFoto" style="width: 100%" class="img-responsive " src="images/semfoto.png" alt="semfoto"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label for="id">ID:</label>
                                    <input disabled="" type="number" class="form-control" id="inpId">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                                    <input required="" maxlength="60" type="text" class="form-control" id="inpNome">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="status">Status de bateria:</label>
                                    <input required   type="text"  class="form-control" id="inpStatusBateria">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="inpTelefone">Telefone</label>
                                    <input required="" type="tel"  onkeypress="funcoes.mascara(this, '## ####-####')" maxlength="12" class="form-control" id="inpTelefone">
                                </div> 

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="hInicio">Horario de inicio:</label>
                                    <input required="" type="datetime" class="form-control" id="inpHinicio">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="hFim">Horario do fim:</label>
                                    <input required="" type="datetime" class="form-control" id="inpHfim">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="inpIdGInformacao">ID Grupo Informação:</label>
                                    <select required="" class="form-control" id="inpIdGInformacao">
                                        <option value="1">info1</option>
                                        <option value="1">info2</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
                                    <input disabled="" value="0"  type="text"   class="form-control" id="inpLatitude">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
                                    <input disabled="" value="0" type="text"  class="form-control" id="inpLongitude">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="corMarker">Cor marker:</label>
                                    <input  type="color" class="form-control" id="inpCorMarker">
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="idExterno">ID Externo:</label>
                                    <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="inpIdExterno">
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="inpInicioRota">Início Rota</label>
                                    <input required="" type="text"  class="form-control" id="inpInicioRota">
                                </div> 

                                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="inpSabado" type="checkbox" value="">Sabado</label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="inpDomingo" type="checkbox" value="">Domingo</label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="inpStatus" type="checkbox" value="">Status</label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="inpConcentrador" type="checkbox" value="">Concentrador</label>
                                </div> 

                            </div> 

                            <div  class="pull-right">
                                <button type="submit" id="btnGravar" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                                <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-primary">Limpar</button>
                                <button type="button" id="btnExcluir" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
                            </div> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divRelacionamentos" class="col-md-4"> 

            </div>

            <div id="divModals"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

`

Comment: quais caracteres especiais você está tentando colocar?

Comment: @ LeonardoAssunção  Nessa página apenas a palavra Informação e as que contém acento, porém nas outras páginas todas apresentam o mesmo problema.

Comment: Os documentos devem estar salvos como ANSI mas a esta usando UTF8, o que ocasiona caracteres como `�`, **leia** esta resposta e veja a parte sobre sublimetext e notepad++: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Estou usando o netBeans e outros projetos não tem o mesmo problema. inclusive verifiquei e estavam iguais a este que teve problemas.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke salve o texto como UTF-8 e tente novamente.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke adicionei o exemplo de como configurar o Netbeans na resposta, mas precisar salvar novamente todos documentos html

Comment: Eu tava usando bloco de notas e eu li aqui sobre salvar ANSI e realmente tava em ANSI, daí eu substituí por Utf-8, na hora em que salva existe essa opção no bloco de notas Campo codificação ao lado de salvar. E funcionou, os acentos são exibidos normalmente. Vlwww

Comment: Não adicione "obrigado" como resposta. Quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes, você poderá [votar a favor de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que considerar úteis. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/213997)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema não se resolverá tirando as meta-tags ou trocando acentos por entidades como `&ccedil;`, neste ultimo caso é apenas uma maneira de contornar, mas não de resolver.

O problema é como os arquivos foram salvos, provavelmente eles foram salvos como ANSI (ou iso-8859-1/windows-1252), pra resolver o problema use programas como SublimeText ou notepad++.

### Os problemas comuns da codificação

É muito comum quando estamos trabalhando com acentos nos depararmos com caracteres estranhos como por exemplo:

- Algo semelhante a `Ã©` que representa o `é`, isto ocorre porque o caractere é unicode, mas a página está em iso-8859-1 (ou outro compatível).
- E o sinal `�` um exemplo de situação é quando você usa um acentos compatíveis com iso-8859-1 em uma página que esta tentando processar UTF-8 devido ao `Content-Type: ...; charset=utf8`.

### Como corrigir

Você deve salvar todos documentos como **utf-8 sem "BOM"**, você pode utilizar softwares como [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ou [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) para converter os arquivos:

- Usando notepad++:

  [image: utf8 sem bom notepad++]
- Usando Sublime Text:

  [image: utf8 sublime text]
- Netbeans vá <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > <kbd>Workspace</kbd> > <kbd>Text File Encoding</kbd>:

  [image: utf8 netbeans]

  > Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452715/1518921
- IntelliJ IDEA vá até <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> em Windows) e no projeto selecionado faça as seguintes seleções pro enconding desejado (no caso o .prorperties eu coloco como utf8 também, mas é opcional):

  [image: inteli]

Comment: Estou usando o Intellij da Jetbrain... como corrigir isso?

Comment: @ThiagoCunha resposta atualizada

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tire as duas linhas:

meta charset="utf-8"

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

e teste novamente

Comment: o problema persiste mesmo removendo as linhas

Comment: Há um espaçamento incorreto na sua primeira tag html, retire-o

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <head>
  <title>Verdeé</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>ééÀÁÁáéá</p>
</body>

Comment: A idéia é boa, mas em vez de tirar seria bom trocar o utf-8 pra iso-8859-1 como teste.

Answer (score 0):

Tente entities.

Exemplo:

Para escrever Canção, você escreveria `Can&ccedil;&atilde;o` onde

- `&ccedil;` = `ç`
- `&atilde;` = `ã` (o ponto e virgula faz parte do código)

Segue um [link](http://ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm) de uma tabela de exemplo

Comment: apesar de funcionar há muitas palavras a serem modificadas.