# É possível fazer a codificação de um banco de dados MySQL ser igual a codificação de uma página PHP/HTML5?

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, collation

Por exemplo, na minha tabela no MySQL a palavra aparece *Crédito* e no banco "CrÃ©dito", *Válido até* no site aparece como "VÃ¡lido atÃ©" no banco.

Estou usando no HTML5 o **UTF-8**, no editor está o *Encoding* como **Encoding in UTF-8-BOM**.

No banco o collation é  **latin1_swedish_ci**.

Existe alguma forma de fazer ficar exatamente igual a codificação tanto no banco quanto no site?

Não adianta trocar o collation para utf8_bin.

Comment: Sim é possivel, veja esta resposta minha: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Obrigado, meu caro.

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer o comentário e a resposta sugerida. Consegui solucionar o problema convertendo tudo para utf-8 e passei a utilizar o mysqli para fazer as conexões. Muito obrigado.