# Erro Baseado em Acentuação

Tags: php, mysql, apache-cordova, api, stored-procedures

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um APP Hibrido que utiliza um Webservice PHP para enviar um e-mail e chamar uma Procedure no MySQL preenchendo ela com os mesmos dados do email ,  até a parte do envio do email está tudo OK ele envia com sucesso , porem no momento que vou enviar os dados para procedure ele simplesmente não da erros e nem executa nada.

Criei um PHP a parte com um formulário e o mesmo conteúdo do webservice que é utilizado pelo APP , quando preencho o formulário  notei que ele monta a URL do GET formatando os dados fazendo os ajustes de acentos e removendo o @ e substituindo por %40 ( codigo ASCII) e assim a procedure roda com sucesso.

No caso do App o PHP Recupera os dados vindos do JSON enviado pelo APP e os transforma em variáveis , já tentei forçar uma conversão de acentos mas não adiantou alguma ideia do que fazer?

Seguem os códigos:

**Versão APP**

```
 <?php

Include("dbconect.php"); #DB Connector

if (!empty($_GET)) {

/* Recuperando Dados do GET */
$DestinoEmail = "webmaster@testfab.com"; //Destino para o Email de     Notificação

$NomeCompleto  = $_GET['Nome'];
$TelefoneFixo  = $_GET['TelefoneFixo'];
$TelefoneMovel = $_GET['TelefoneMovel'];
$email         = $_GET['Mail'];
$cor           = $_GET['CorSelecionada'];
$Rg            = $_GET['NumeroRG'];
$cep           = $_GET['NumeroCEP'];
$assunto       = $_GET['AssuntoEmail'];
$descricao     = $_GET['descricaoEmail'];
$mobileID      = $_GET['MobileReg'];
$sexo          = $_GET['Sex'];
$nCasa         = "0";

/* Envia o email notificando */

#Corpo do Email
$msg= "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <style type='text/css'>
          body {

           color: #3A6EA5;
          }

          h5 {
              background-color: #3A6EA5;
              padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
              width: 950px;
          }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Prezado $NomeCompleto,</p>
          <p>Seu Teste foi encaminhado com sucesso para nossa linha , favor aguarde retorno.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </body>
    </html>";

# Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@testemat.com>' . "\r\n";
$assuntoMail = "Teste de Material";
#Codificar Assunto para aceitar os acentos 
$assunto_codificado = sprintf('=?%s?%s?%s?=', 'UTF-8', 'B', base64_encode($assuntoMail)); 
#Quebra de Linha caso a linha ultrapasse 70 caracteres
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
#Envio do Email
mail($DestinoEmail,$assunto_codificado ,$msg,$headers);

/*  Executar a Proc para armazenar os dados       */


$ncasa = "0";
$sth = $db->prepare('CALL     PR_REGISTER_REPORT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@out)');
$sth->bindParam(1,  $NomeCompleto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(2,  $TelefoneFixo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(3,  $TelefoneMovel, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(4,  $email, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(5,  $cor, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(6,  $Rg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(7,  $cep, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(8,  $ncasa, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(9,  $mobileID, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(10, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(11, $assunto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(12, $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();


//Retorno OK para o APP
$resultados["validate"] = "ok";
$resultadosJson = json_encode($resultados);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';


}else{

Echo "Interface Somente com APP";

}

?>
```

**Versão Teste (test-process.php)**

```
<?php

  Include("dbconect.php"); #DB Connector

  if (!empty($_GET)) {

  /* Recuperando Dados do GET */
  $DestinoEmail = "webmaster@testfab.com"; //Destino para o Email de       Notificação

  $NomeCompleto  = $_GET['Nome'];
  $TelefoneFixo  = $_GET['TelefoneFixo'];
  $TelefoneMovel = $_GET['TelefoneMovel'];
  $email         = $_GET['Mail'];
  $cor           = $_GET['CorSelecionada'];
  $Rg            = $_GET['NumeroRG'];
  $cep           = $_GET['NumeroCEP'];
  $assunto       = $_GET['AssuntoEmail'];
  $descricao     = $_GET['descricaoEmail'];
  $mobileID      = $_GET['MobileReg'];
  $sexo          = $_GET['Sex'];
  $nCasa         = "0";

  /* Envia o email notificando */

  #Corpo do Email
  $msg= "<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <style type='text/css'>
          body {

           color: #3A6EA5;
          }

          h5 {
              background-color: #3A6EA5;
              padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
              width: 950px;
          }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Prezado $NomeCompleto,</p>
          <p>Seu Teste foi encaminhado com sucesso para nossa linha , favor aguarde retorno.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </body>
    </html>";

# Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@testemat.com>' . "\r\n";
$assuntoMail = "Teste de Material";
#Codificar Assunto para aceitar os acentos 
$assunto_codificado = sprintf('=?%s?%s?%s?=', 'UTF-8', 'B', base64_encode($assuntoMail)); 
#Quebra de Linha caso a linha ultrapasse 70 caracteres
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
#Envio do Email
mail($DestinoEmail,$assunto_codificado ,$msg,$headers);

/*  Executar a Proc para armazenar os dados       */


$ncasa = "0";
$sth = $db->prepare('CALL     PR_REGISTER_REPORT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@out)');
$sth->bindParam(1,  $NomeCompleto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(2,  $TelefoneFixo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(3,  $TelefoneMovel, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(4,  $email, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(5,  $cor, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(6,  $Rg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(7,  $cep, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(8,  $ncasa, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(9,  $mobileID, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(10, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(11, $assunto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(12, $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();


//Retorno OK para o APP
$resultados["validate"] = "ok";
$resultadosJson = json_encode($resultados);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';


}else{

echo"

<form action='test-process.php' method='get'>
Nome Completo:<br>
<input type='text' name='Nome' value=''><br>
Telefone Fixo:<br>
<input type='text' name='TelefoneFixo' value=''><br>
 Telefone Movel:<br>
<input type='text' name='TelefoneMovel' value=''><br>
  Email:<br>
<input type='text' name='Mail' value=''><br>
 Cor:<br>
<input type='text' name='CorSelecionada' value=''><br>
 NumeroRG:<br>
<input type='text' name='NumeroRG' value=''><br>
NumeroCEP:<br>
<input type='text' name='NumeroCEP' value=''><br>
 AssuntoEmail:<br>
<input type='text' name='AssuntoEmail' value=''><br>
  DescricaoEmail:<br>
<input type='text' name='descricaoEmail' value=''><br>
  MobileReg:<br>
<input type='text' name='MobileReg' value=''><br>
Sex:<br>
<input type='text' name='Sex' value=''><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>";


}

?>
```

Alguma solução?

> Tentei forçar apartir do get um utf8_decode($foo), e a entrada com
>   utf8_encode($foo) mas não adiantou =(

Comment: Já tentou forçar a saída com utf8_decode($foo), e a entrada com utf8_encode($foo) ?

Comment: Tentei forçar apartir do get um utf8_decode($foo), e a entrada com utf8_encode($foo) mas não adiantou =(

Comment: Percebi que criou duas contas diferentes, recomendo que entre em contato através da página http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact e solicite mescla das contas

Comment: Feito! muito Obrigado!

Comment: Tentou usar `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` e `mb_http_output('UTF-8')`, basicamente essas linhas vão dizer que você está trabalhando com strings UTF-8 em todo o arquivo.

Comment: Siga o passo a passo desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, provavelmente irá resolver

Answer (score -1):

tenta usar `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conec);`