# problema em armazenar caracteres com acentos

Tags: php, html, mysqli

olá! meu banco de dados está em utf8 e em todas as paginas eu coloco o seguinte código:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($_SG['servidor'], $_SG['usuario'], $_SG['senha'],$_SG['banco']);

   mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");//converte tudo em utf-8 \/
   mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
   mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_client=utf8');
   mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

e na hora de armazenar e exibir caracteres especiais estava dando tudo certo.
mas de um dia pro outro, sem eu ter mudado nada, isso parou de funcionar. na hora de armazenar dados por um formulário, ele armazena 'ã' como 'Ã£'. e se eu armazenar os dados diretamente no banco de dados ele armazena normalmente.

o que faço?? OBS: o problema está em armazenar o caractere com acentuação e não em exibir.

adicionei o valor 'sã' no campo 'classi_atv_econ'. 
o valor hexadecimal é o seguinte:
[image: valor hexadecimal]

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Cadastrar Empresa</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
include("seguranca.php"); // Inclui o arquivo com o sistema de segurança
?>

</head>
<body>
<?php


include 'conexao.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($_SG['servidor'], $_SG['usuario'], $_SG['senha'],$_SG['banco']);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
exit;
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8')) {
printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($con));
exit;
}

$nom_empre = $_POST['nom_empre'];             
$inscri_muni = $_POST['inscri_muni'];
$situacao = $_POST['situacao'];
$cpf_cnpj_empre = $_POST['cpf_cnpj_empre'];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO empresa 
(nom_empre,inscri_muni,situacao,cpf_cnpj_empre)VALUES ('$nom_empre','$inscri_muni','$situacao','$cpf_cnpj_empre')";

$cadastra = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
if (!empty($cadastra){
header("location:home.php");
} 
else {
echo "Não foi possível inserir os dados, tente novamente.";
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:
echo ("Dados sobre o erro:" . mysqli_error($con));

 }
```

código da pagina que envia o formulario:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->

<title> Cadastrar </title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style/login2.css" rel="stylesheet">




<?php


include("seguranca.php"); // Inclui o arquivo com o sistema de segurança
protegePagina(); // Chama a função que protege a página
admin();
expulsaUsuarioComum();
manutencao();

$con = mysqli_connect($_SG['servidor'], $_SG['usuario'], $_SG['senha'],      $_SG['banco']);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
exit;
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8')) {
printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($con));
exit;
}
?>
```

o restante do código é html normal. apenas um formulario. nao mexo com php no restante do código

> http://piratepad.net/Fbx5o7qZ1d

Comment: Esta resposta explica tudo, desde header, conexão, como salvar os arquivos, e explica porque caracteres assim `Ã£` aparecem http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: As instruções são pra tanto armazenar quanto exibir, o tal caractere é unicode `Ã£` ele está correto, UNICODE é UTF8, se fizer o passo a passo na resposta que linkei irá resolver, a resposta não fala apenas de exibição, mas de tudo o que é necessário pra usar o UTF8.

Comment: já vi. fiz tudo oq pede, mas continua o erro. o problema está em armazenar o caractere. e nao em exibir.

Comment: Seu problema é de duplo encoding. Um dado UTF-8 foi reconvertido em UTF-8. Pra ter uma idéia, só vendo seu código de inserção. Em algum lugar do código tem uma conversão de encoding indevida.

Comment: coloquei um link do piratepad co o codigo compketo