# Consulta com like não retorna nada quando tem mais de uma palavra no PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta usando like no PHP e quando eu uso uma mais de uma palavra.
Só funciona se eu colocar apenas uma palavra.
No SQL Server a consulta funciona **sem erros**.

```
    <?php

 function listaMatHistOS($conn, $equipamento){
        $HistMatOS = array();
        $where = [];
        $where[] = "cliente.id = (select usuario.idCliente from usuario where usuario.login = '".usuarioLogado()."')";

        if ($equipamento) {
        $where[] = "material.nome like '%{$equipamento}%'";         
        }
        $SQL = "select os.id as IdOS, os.dataHora, material.nome as equipamento, itemMaterial.nSerie, itemMaterial.patrimonio, 
            itemMaterial.rm, os.status 
from os

inner join itemMaterial on
itemMaterial.id = os.id 

inner join material on
material.id = itemMaterial.idMaterial

inner join cliente on
cliente.id = os.idCliente

where " . implode(' AND ', $where) ;
        $resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);
        while ($RelMatOS = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){;
        array_push($HistMatOS, $RelMatOS);
    }
    echo $SQL;
    return $HistMatOS;
 }
```

[image: Consulta sem retorno]

Comment: Qual registro você esperava que seu `like` encontrasse?

Comment: Todos os equipamentos que possuem **Móddulo ECG**.  
No SQL Server retornar 6 registros e no PHP nenhum.

Comment: Aquela mesma `query` do `print` que você colocou na resposta retorna 6 registros se você copiar e colocar no `SQL Studio`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/9KFSw
Olha o print, pfv.

Comment: Tenta mudar o `%` para `'%%'`

Comment: Não funcionou.,,

Comment: igual o que eu coloquei? com as `'` e td?

Comment: Eu descobri que quando eu consulto **módulo ecg** não retorna nada mas se eu consultar **dulo ecg** retorna os valores.
Ou seja,
O problema está no acento.
Tenho que remover no input.

Comment: antes de mandar sua $SQL faz um `$SQL = utf8_encode($SQL);` então

Comment: @Sorack.
Altera para decode para que eu marque a sua resposta

Comment: Devo lhe aconselhar que usar utf8_decode para resolver este caso será praticamente uma gambiarra (não quer dizer que utf8_decode é gambiarra, mas o uso para resolver este problema especifico), o problema esta em outro lugar, esta resposta deve lhe orientar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, apesar de falar sobre mysql, a lógica seguida é a mesma, tem que corrigir o encoding dos .php, os headers e as conexões com o banco. Agora se estiver usar is-8859-1 (ou window-1252) junto com ajax, ae realmente só utf8_decode. Poderia confirmar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a palavra sem acentuação funciona corretamente na busca o problema provavelmente é o `encoding` utilizado que para `sqlsrv_query`é `ISO-8859-1`. Então antes de executar sua `query` faça o `decode`:

```
$SQL = utf8_decode($SQL);
```

Que irá transformar seu `UTF-8` para `ISO-8859-1`.