# encoding do php ao banco mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encode

Bom, estou com um problema com o `encode` na hora de lançar dados numa tabela `mysql` pelo `php`, minha página está com `encode utf-8`, meu banco usando `latin1`, porém, não sei como faço tal conversão, se altero o encode do site, sou obrigado a escrever com os caracteres de tal encode, mas para o usuário final ficaria horrível ter de usar o mesmo, por exemplo, um usuário teria de digitar `&Atilde` para obter `Ã`.
Sendo assim, gostaria de saber como posso resolver este problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, se você usa mysql, você pode codificar fazendo da seguinte foma no seu arquivo de conexão com o banco:

```
  mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysqli_query($link,'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
  mysqli_query($link,'SET charecter_set_client=utf8');
  mysqli_query($link,'SET charecter_set_results=utf8');
```

E no seu HTML, la no cabeçalho, coloque a seguinte metatag:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

E pronto. Isso deve resolver os seus problemas....
Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: uso o comando mysqli, mas ainda assim a base de dados é em mysql, não ?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi compreendi errado. É sim

Comment: Então, muda ali e põe no formato mysqli, e tudo certo

Comment: Assim que eu puder eu vou testar, caso funcione ou não, aviso aqui e marco resposta, obrigado pela prontidão :)

Comment: Blz. Qualquer coisa só comentar ai... Editei ali.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Answer (score 4):

Se você REALMENTE precisa trabalhar com estes dois encodings diferentes, pode ser interessante usar estas duas funções, para não depender de conversões na conexão:

Para ler de uma origem Latin1: e usar em UTF-8:

```
$dados_em_utf8 = utf8_encode( $dados_em_latin1 );
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php

Para ler de uma origem UTF-8 e usar em Latin1:

```
$dados_em_latin1 = utf8_decode( $dados_em_utf8 );
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php

Se usa `mysqli`, é bom conhecer esta função:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Ela serve para setar o formato de dados da conexão entre o servidor e o PHP (e é um jeito mais direto de configurar a conexão sem precisar fazer *query* com `SET`)

Lembre-se que o "REALMENTE" que eu comentei na 1a linha geralmente implica em uma das duas coisas não ser sua (ou o DB ou as páginas), pois se são, dificilmente você vai ter uma razão legítima para misturar dois encodings.

O melhor mesmo é converter ou o DB ou a aplicação, para que ambas fiquem no mesmo *encoding*.

Para isto, precisa destas três etapas:

- FAZER BACKUP (não adianta chorar se não fizer e algo der errado)
- `ALTER DATABASE banco CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
  Isto não altera os dados, apenas configura o banco para o encoding desejado.
- `ALTER TABLE nomedatabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
  Agora sim está convertendo os DADOS da tabela para utf8

Pode ser mais interessante o `utf8_unicode_ci` do que o `utf8_general_ci` se quiser uma precisão maior nos caracteres comparados.

Mais detalhes aqui:

> [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/70)