# Problema ao salvar textos na linguagem árabe no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um site onde existe varias línguas, porém ao tentar salvar um campo texto na Língua árabe, o mesmo salva com caracteres do tipo "Ø§ÙØµÙØ­Ø© Ø§ÙØ±Ø¦ÙØ³ÙØ©", já tente mudar o chatset do mysql para utf8 e cp1256, mesmo assim o erro continua.

Obs: plataforma de dev. ainda esta utilizando mysql_

Comment: Brendol esta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 explica como usar UTF8 com PHP e Mysql.

Comment: Não é utilizar UTF8 em paginas, e sim salvar textos na Língua árabe, se o problema fosse UTF8 seria simples =)

Comment: Brendol sendo UTF8 ou não lá explica como fazer o charset funciona, deve configurar a conexão com mysql, salvar os arquivos na codificação necessaria (todos), a explicação lá vale para qualquer tipo de charset, o importante é entender o passo a passo só trocando utf8 pelo que desejar. Tente seguir os passos. Não basta mudar um charset apenas, tem que ler todas as dicas e entende-las ;)

Comment: Irei dar uma olhada, obg.

Answer (score 1):

`ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

já usei uma vez e funcionou ([referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31904985/4551469))

Comment: Coloca no topo da página php que vai processar os textos

Comment: Não deu certo =/

Answer (score 1):

O @GuilhermeNascimento está certo. Você tem que usar codificação de caracteres UTF-8:

**1. Na página**

**2. Na conexão com o banco de dados**

**3. No banco de dados mesmo**