# UTF8 em conexão MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Tenho uma conexão PHP PDO com dois bancos de dados, porém, estou com problemas com o caracteres especiais de ambos. Como resolver?

```
$host = "localhost";
$user  = "user";
$password =  "";
$database1 = "bd1";
$database2 = "bd2";

try {
    $dbh1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database1", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to the database:' . $e);
}

try {
    $dbh2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database2", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to the database:' . $e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Lembre-se: _charset_ igual no banco e na aplicação. Veja se isso aqui ajuda: [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/42307).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//observe o charset=utf8 na DSN
try {
    $dbh1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database1;charset=utf8", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to the database:' . $e);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo. Mt obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi alterando o arquivo my.ini, adicionando as duas linhas abaixo

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html