# PHP que retorna null campos de tabela que não estão vazios nem nulos no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest

Tenho uma tabela "formas_pagamento" e fiz uma API pra pegar todas estas formas de pagamento, mas mesmo o banco de dados estando correto, ele informa que o campo "nome" é null no retorno, vejam:

```
[{"nome":"Dinheiro"},{"nome":"Cheque"},{"nome":null},{"nome":null}]
```

E não está "null" e só aparecem estes dois.

Segue meu PHP:

PHP:

```
    <?php


header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';

//$cod_fornecedor=$_GET['cod_fornecedor'];


$query="SELECT
   nome
FROM
   formas_pagamento
ORDER BY
   cod_forma_pagamento ASC";


$result=$con->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

O que há de errado?

Comment: Qual a diferença entre: `$row_cnt` e `$result->num_rows`? Pode exibir os dois em um ECHO?

Comment: Dá uma lida nesse post. É possível que seja o mesmo problema
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143163/php-json-encode-shows-null-instead-of-text

Comment: Muda sua query para SELECT
   CONVERT(nome USING utf8) as nome
FROM
   formas_pagamento
ORDER BY
   cod_forma_pagamento ASC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando json_encode(utf8ize($row));

Segue o PHP novo completo:

```
   $rest_api = array();
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}

/** connect to mysql **/
$mysql = new mysqli($config["host"], $config["user"], $config["pass"], $config["dbase"]);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}


$query="SELECT nome FROM formas_pagamento ORDER BY cod_forma_pagamento ASC";

$result = $mysql->query($query);
//$result=$con->query($query);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;

            echo json_encode(utf8ize($row));

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Há funções próprias que já fazem a associação dos resultados, não precisa percorrer manualmente e reinventar a roda, correndo o risco de criar erros. Utilize a função [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
$query = "SELECT nome FROM formas_pagamento ORDER BY cod_forma_pagamento ASC";

$result = $con->query($query);

$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Porque complicar e "convidar" aos erros?. Há forma bem mais fácil de fazer isso (código não testado):

```
$output = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
  $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Não seria só usar um fetch_all em vez desse loop?

Comment: o Bacco tem razão: fui levado pelo fetch_assoc() do código original, quando poderia muito bem usar fetch_all()

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de uma maneira mais simplificada que funcionará perfeitamente:

```
$query="SELECT
   nome
FROM
   formas_pagamento
ORDER BY
   cod_forma_pagamento ASC";

$arr = [];
foreach ($con->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Em caso de dúvidas, acesse http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 1):

O `json_encode` requer UTF-8, provavelmente este já é o formato do seu banco, mas você talvez não tenha especificado isso na conexão, como eu explico nesta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Se for OOP:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', $mysqli->connect_errno);
    exit;
}

/*
 * compatibilidade para to 5.2.9 e 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

//Define para UTF-8
if (false === $mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```

Com mysqli procedural:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

//Define para UTF-8
if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}
```

**Não é necessário** ficar usando `utf8_encode` de maneira recursiva, como fez em sua resposta, basta entender o que é UTF-8 e saber como aplica-lo, a resposta que eu linkei mostra o passo a passo.