# Problema de acentuação ao migrar para o PHP7

Tags: php, php-7, php-5

Estou usando collation *latin1* nas colunas do banco e *iso-8859-1* nas paginas, enquanto estava no PHP5 funcionava normal, mas ao migrar para PHP7 os acentos começaram a dar problemas aparecendo isto `�` no lugar de cada acento.

O PHP7 mudou a forma que trabalha com acentos se comparado ao PHP5?

Comment: Você apagou a outra e recriou a mesma, isso não é um bom uso do site. Se uma pergunta toma negativo, o certo é tentar seguir as orientações em [ask] e melhorá-la editando, não ficar recriando a pergunta

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz muito sentido, está bem vaga. Não vejo relação alguma entre a versão da linguagem e a codificação do banco, o fato de migrar não significa que resulte em problema, desde que estejam sob o mesmo encoding.

Comment: agora sim, vc me deu uma explicação plausivel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não a codificação dos documentos não tem haver com a linguagem, a linguagem apenas processa e envia um arquivo processado novamente ao usuário, quando a conexão com o banco é algo que por padrão é configurado no banco e não no PHP.

A configuração do banco depende totalmente do que o desenvolvedor vai desejar fazer, aqui tem uma resposta sobre o assunto, apesar do foto ser PHP nela é valido para qualquer linguagem que seja voltado para Web (ou seja que gera páginas):

- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

Note que qualquer versão do PHP tenta manter a retrocompatibilidade, então as novas funcionalidades do PHP7 não necessariamente tornam scripts mais antigos incompatíveis, a não ser que esteja usando uma função ou classe que tenha sido previamente descontinuada.

Para explicar melhor, no caso o mysqli é uma API que faz o PHP acessar o banco mysql que pode estar em uma porta ou servidor separado, o seu unico problema seria se estive-se usando funções que começam assim `mysql_`, pois elas eram parte da API mais antiga que já estava marcada como obsoleta desde o *PHP 5.5.0* e só ficou disponivel até o *5.6* por questão de retro-compatibilidade. Agora na versão *7.0.0+* ela foi removida e scripts escritos usando ela não funcionarão mais.

### Configurando o charset no banco

Mesmo que fizer isto (PDO):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BANCO;charset=utf-8', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
$conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');//Define o charset como UTF-8
```

Ou isto (mysqli):

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')
```

Não quer dizer que você esta configurando o PHP, na verdade você esta enviando uma instrução para o banco para que ele devolva como foi pedido os resultados.

No caso de bancos uma página web e php tradicionais será composta de 4 coisas importantes:

- Servidor HTTP (apache, nginx, IIS, etc)
- Linguagem PHP que interpreta os scripts e devolve como resposta
- banco de dados
- Scripts `.php` que você escreveu:

Todos os 4 tem que ter as configurações de codificação necessárias:

- Servidor HTTP: pode se resolver no httpd.conf ou no .htaccess, se bem que você usar `header('Content-Type: ...');` do proprio PHP já resolve, ou seja só será necessário configurar para arquivos estáticos (o que na verdade pode ser opcional)
- Linguagem PHP: setar o `header('Content-Type: ...');`
- Banco de dados: deve usar a instrução `SET CHARACTER SET ...` ou `$mysqli->set_charset('...')` para dizer o que espera
- Scripts `.php` que você escreveu: devem ser salvos com a codificação desejada, se for UTF-8 use "UTF-8 sem BOM", se for latin1 ou semelhante salve os scripts como ANSI ou windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 ou compatíveis.

Comment: O que aconteceu foi assim, eu migrei pro PHP 7 e ao mesmo tempo me ofereceram hospedar meus sites nas nuvens. Foi maior confusão, caracteres acentuados com ? aai voltei para a versão anterior. Porém estou achando que essa confusão toda é porque a migração pra tal nuvem ainda não foi finalizada.

Comment: Mas valeu sua resposta, assim que acabar a migração para as nuvens, volto com a versão 7

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo isto deve ter sido problema no Apache e não no PHP, o seu problema pode ser evitado seguido o passo-a-passo da resposta que eu linkei http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, é uma coisa que vivo repetindo para o pessoa, setar um header, ou uma meta-tag, ou usar utf8_encode/utf8_decode é apenas "remendos", vc tem que fazer o passo-a-passo da resposta, eu criei ela mesmo por ver muitas respostas aqui no site que realmente não passavam de gambiarras, tente seguir ela e verá que é uma questão de organizar as coisas.

Comment: valeu mesmo, muito agradecido pela atenção, pelo menos existe alguém com bom senso neste site!!!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo tomei a liberdade de editar sua pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197152/3635 e deixei um upvote. Até mais.

Comment: Você  é o cara, mais uma vez muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Alterei o  charset para UTF8 e collation para utf8_general_ci e nas páginas coloquei  meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8. Mas continua a aparecer �. Que mais devo fazer?

Comment: Eu recomendo _fortemente_ a leitura desse artigo aqui. Não vai mudar o que tem que ser feito em cada ponto da configurç~ao, mas vai ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo em cada ponto: http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Comment: @jsbueno https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: a resposta linkada não tem a ver com as respostas específicas para essa pergunta (mas estão relacionados com o problema que motivou a pergunta) - tem a ver com ser 2018, e as pessoas ainda agirem sem entenderem o que já era considerado um mínimo para saber trabalalhar com caracteres acentuados (em qualquer linguagem) num artigo de _2003_

Comment: @jsbueno vou explicar de outra maneira pra que fique evidente pra ti, existe uma problema é o entendimento das pessoas, elas nem sabem o que é codificação (codec), se este é um problema que nos afeta até hoje então você deveria formular uma pergunta com resposta e detalhar o assunto nelas, ali no link eu expliquei o passo a passo e o porque codec X não funciona junto com codec Y, agora se for para ser mais "abrangente" faça o que eu lhe sugeri (criar um topico especifico) e garanto que você terá muitos resultados positivos.

Answer (score 1):

Muito provavelmente há um conflito com a configuração do ambiente. Pois segundo o que relatou, no ambiente anterior estava tudo funcionando. Além do mais, o PHP7 não traz mudanças que afetem a codificação/encoding em relação ao PHP5. todavia, pode existir alguma função ou parâmetro obsoleto ou removido nessa nova versão, o qual o seu sistema ainda utiliza e pode estar desencadeando erros que por fim afetam a maneira como o sistema deve lidar com o encoding. Se for esse o caso, não há como resolver aqui pois exige um profundo diagnóstico do seu sistema. Apesar disso, há certos pontos básicos e lógicos que podem resolver

## MBString

Verifique como estão as configurações do [MBString](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). Deve estar atento a esses parâmetros: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php

Um jeito prático é rodar o `phpinfo();` e comparar as informações. http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

## Servidor web

Verifique também as configurações de codificação do servidor WEB. (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc).

## Banco de dados

Obviamente, deve verificar também as configurações do banco de dados, caso possua.

Pode ter ocorrido de ter migrado para um banco de dados contendo configurações incompatíveis e ocasionado o corrompimento dos dados ou simplesmente um conflito que pode ser consertado. No caso de corrompimento não tem mágica, terá que refazer a partir de um backup seguro. Acho isso pouco proválvel. Mas é uma opção caso as anteriores, descritas acima, não resolvam.