# caracteres especias todo quebrado

Tags: php, html

Meu "echo" abaixo esta trazendo do banco de dados os caracteres especias todo quebrado como concerta essa situação ????

```
<html>

<head>
      <title>Resultados da busca</title>
<!-- Ligação com o css -->    

</head>

<body>

<br /><br />
<!-- Ligação com o banco -->
<?php include 'css/config.php'; ?>


<?php
//Variáveis que recebem os dados preenchidos no formulário (cadastroProfTela1.html)
   session_start();
$uni= utf8_decode( $_POST[uni] );
$mod= utf8_decode( $_POST[mod] );
$ano= utf8_decode( $_POST[ano] );
$turma=$_POST['turma'];
$turno= utf8_decode( $_POST[turno] );
//Variáveis globais (podem ser utilizadas em todas as outras páginas do sistema)   
   $_SESSION['uni'] = $uni;
   $_SESSION['mod'] = $mod;
   $_SESSION['ano'] = $ano;
   $_SESSION['turma'] = $turma;
   $_SESSION['turno'] = $turno;   
   //Select no banco para selecionar todos os dados solicitados no formulário (cadastroProfTela1.html) 
   $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM cadastros WHERE unidade LIKE '%".$uni."%' AND modalidade LIKE '%".$mod."%' AND ano LIKE '%".$ano."%' 
   AND turma LIKE '%".$turma."%' AND turno LIKE '%".$turno."%'");
//Testa se os dados existem no banco, caso exista ele exibe na tela   
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
   if ($row > 0) {
       while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
           $id=$linha['id'];
           $reg=$linha['regional'];
           $rpa=$linha['rpa'];
           $tpu1=$linha['tipoUnidade'];
           $uni=$linha['unidade'];
           $mod=$linha['modalidade'];
           $ano=$linha['ano'];
   $turma= utf8_decode( $linha[turma] );
           $turno=$linha['turno'];
           $situacaoTurma=$linha['situacaoTurma'];         
           $matricula=$linha['matricula'];
                   $cpf=$linha['cpf'];
           $nomeProfEfetivo=$linha['nomeProfEfetivo'];
           $cargo=$linha['cargo'];
        }
        if ($matricula != "") {
            echo "<strong>ID: </strong>".@$id;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Regional: </strong>".@$reg;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>RPA: </strong>".@$rpa;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Tipo de Unidade : </strong>".@$tpu1;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Unidade de Ensino: </strong>".@$uni;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Modalidade de Ensino: </strong>".@$mod;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Ano de Ensino: </strong>".@$ano;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Turma: </strong>".@$turma;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Turno: </strong>".@$turno;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Situação da Turma: </strong>".@$situacaoTurma;        
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong> Matrícula do Professor Titular: </strong>".@$matricula;          
           echo "<br /><br />";
                    echo "<strong>CPF do Professor Titular: </strong>".@$matricula;        
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Nome do Professor Titular: </strong>".@$nomeProfEfetivo;          
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong> Cargo do Professor Titular: </strong>".@$cargo;
           echo "<br /><br /><br />";
           echo "<h3>A turma já possui professor titular. Deseja alterar essa informação?</h3>";
           echo "<html>
                 <head>
                     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/SLP/css/css/simenao.css' />
                 </head>
                 <body>

                         <div style='width:100px; float:left'> 
                         <form name='alterarTurma' method='post' action='/SLP/cadastro de professor/pag3'>
                             <input type='submit' class='ct btn-blue' value='SIM' />                             
                         </form>
                         </div>
                                             <div style='width:100px; float:left '> 
                         <form name='removerTurmaMenu' method='post' action='/SLP/cadastro de professor/pag1'>
                             <input type='submit' class='ct btn-blue' value='NÃO' />
                         </form>                         
                     </div>
                 </body>
                 </html>";
        }else { 

           echo "<strong>ID: </strong>".@$id;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Regional: </strong>".@$reg;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>RPA: </strong>".@$rpa;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Tipo de Unidade: </strong>".@$tpu1;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Unidade de Ensino: </strong>".@$uni;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Modalidade de Ensino: </strong>".@$mod;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Ano de Ensino: </strong>".@$ano;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Turma: </strong>" .@$turma;      
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Turno: </strong>".@$turno;
           echo "<br /><br />";
           echo "<strong>Situação da Turma: </strong>".@$situacaoTurma;           
           echo "<br /><br /><br />";
           echo "<html>
                 <head>

                 </head>
                 <body>

                         <form name='cadastroProf' method='post' action='/SLP/cadastro de professor/pag3'>
                                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/SLP/css/css/finalizar.css'>
                                 <input type='submit' class='btfinalizar btn-blue' value='Incluir Professor' />


                         </form>

                 </body>
                 </html>";
       }
   }
    else{

         echo "<html>
   <head>

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/SLP/css/css/Pag.css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container2'>
Turma não encontrada!
</div>
</body>

</html>";

   }
?>

</br></br></br>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLP/css/css/voltar.css">
<a href="/SLP/cadastro de professor/pag1" class="bt btn-blue">Voltar</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Esta falando dos acentos?

Comment: Notei que esta usando utf8_decode, se necessita desta função significa que você não configurou a conexão, ou header, ou encode da página adequadamente. Acaso este seja o caso escolha, quer usar iso-8859-1 ou utf-8, depois de escolhido siga o passo-a-passo em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 (mude de utf8 para iso-8859-1/latin1 se for não for usar utf-8)

Comment: Não entendi muito o que você falou eu uso o utf_decode para que os POST entre no banco sem quebra os caracteres com um f no final prejudicando minha extração de consulta no banco. Essa mudação e que você sugeriu foi no "decode" ou foi em outro lugar???

Comment: Justamente, se vc esta usando é porque os dados estão vindo misturados, vc não definiu bem, no caso teus scripts estão misturando iso-88859-1 (ou compativel) com utf-8 (Unicode). Não é uma coisa exata o que você fez. Para que funcione bem tem que seguir o passo-a-passo que eu lhe indiquei no link, pois se precisa do utf8_decode para tratar o $_POST é porque tem alguma coisa muito errada.