# Buscar bairro a partir de logradouro

Tags: php

Procurando um pouco achei esse método de consultar o CEP a partir de bairro e cidade ou todos os dados a partir do CEP. Mas essa consulta só esta funcionando quando coloco a informação diretamente no código entre aspas. Não estou conseguindo usar uma variável (que insiro os dados passados por POST) dentro de `$buscarcep->busca('[Aqui dentro!]')`.

O prolema é la em baixo em // Rotina de Exibir

Esse é o código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento</title>
</head>

<body>



<?php
$rua01 = 'Rua diadema';
$cidade01 = 'Foz do Iguaçu';

$endereco01 = $rua01.' '.$cidade01;

class BuscaCEP
{
    protected function formata($response)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($response);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $values = $xpath->query('//*[@class="respostadestaque"]');
        $result = [];

        // Se não encontrar CEP, retorna false
        if (!$values->length) {
            return false;
        }

        // Obtém informações desejadas, tratando-as quando necessário
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $result[] = preg_replace(
                '~[\s]{2,}~',
                '',
                trim($value->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue)
            );
        }

        list($logradouro, $bairro, $localidade, $cep) = $result;
        list($localidade, $uf) = explode('/', $localidade);

        return compact('logradouro', 'bairro', 'localidade', 'uf', 'cep');
    }

    public function busca($cep)
    {
        $response = file_get_contents(
            'http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do',
            false,
            stream_context_create([
                'http' => [
                    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query([
                        'cepEntrada' => $cep,
                        'metodo' => 'buscarCep',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        );

        return $this->formata($response);
    }
}

// Rotina de Exibir
$buscarcep = new BuscaCEP();
$dados = $buscarcep->busca($endereco01);
print_r($dados['bairro']);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Já coloquei

```
$dados = $buscarcep->busca($enderecoP);
$dados = $buscarcep->busca("$enderecoP");
```

E simplesmente não apareceu nada. Nenhum erro, simplesmente não foi impresso nada.

Atualizando com mais informações, pois geraram formas distintas de interpretação. La no final do codigo quando eu coloco:

```
// Rotina de Exibir
$buscarcep = new BuscaCEP();
$dados = $buscarcep->busca($endereco01);
print_r($dados['bairro']);
```

Dentro da variavel **$endereco01** eu tenho **$rua01.' '.$cidade01**, que se eu desse um echo nela, seria mostrado ***Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu***.
Mas da forma como esta não reconhece! Agora se eu tirar **$endereco01** e colocar apenas 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu' dessa forma:

```
// Rotina de Exibir
$buscarcep = new BuscaCEP();
$dados = $buscarcep->busca('Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu');
print_r($dados['bairro']);
```

Ele reconhece perfeitamente e me monstra as informações desse endereço.

Comment: Aqui o output foi **Jardim Curitibano**, funciona. Habilite os erros.

Comment: Quais os valores de `$rua01` e `$cidade01`? Não deveriam ser `$ruaP` e `$cidadeP`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, acabei colocando errado, eu estou usando 01 no final, mas pra passar aqui resolvi colocar P.

Comment: E mesmo assim não funciona? Tente colocar `var_dump($enderecoP)` antes de `$buscarcep->busca(...)`

Comment: @PapaCharlie esta funcionando pq se vc reparar esta --- $dados = $buscarcep->busca('85869510'); --- Tem o cep ja dentro, oq eu quero colocar é uma variável no lugar do numero, pois vou passar por POST essa informação.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não, como me disse ele imprimiu
C:\wamp64\www\delivery2\teste\index.php:69:string 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu' (length=26)
No caso esse 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu' sao os dados que eu estou passando por POST.

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeitamente da maneira que você fez, não alterei linha alguma o problema deve estar em outra parte, não tem nenhuma relação com entrar ou não em `$buscarcep->busca(...)`, as variaveis POST inclusive não são enviadas para `$buscarcep->busca();`, você esta enviando um `'85869510'`. O problema com certeza é no momento que vc passa o POST, ou melhor nem deve estar chegando no POST. Mostre como vc esta fazendo a busca pelo endereço ao invés de CEP.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que deveria ter tirado esse '85869510', pois estão me interpretando errado. O código como esta, esta funcionando. Mas preciso colocar esse CEP diretamente no código. Um exemplo, se disser que $cepConsulta = '85869510'; e colocar $cepConsulta dentro $buscarcep->busca(Aqui dentro), ele simplesmente não reconhece essa o conteúdo dessa variável quando esta ali dentro.

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes já expliquei, o problema não é ae, vc tem que explicar como fez, espera um pouco que estou formulando uma resposta que talvez lhe ajude.

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes como você está chamando esse script? A partir de uma submissão de um formulário?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss agora mesmo estou direto no php, tirei o if(isset(...), ou seja, cada vez que atualizo a pagina ele executando o Script

Comment: Mas se você não está fazendo uma submissão de um formulário, você não terá informações em $_POST. Possivelmente sobre isso que o Guilherme responderá. E que `if(isset(...))` é esse que não está no código?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acontece assim: se eu colocar nos pontinos $buscarcep->busca(...)    '85869510', ele busca as informações sobre esse CEP, mas se eu colocar tbm diretamente nos pontinhos 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu' ele também busca as informações sobre esse endereço. Agora se eu colocar 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu' dentro de uma variavel, $cepConsulta por exemplo, e colocar essa variável dentro dos pontinhos, ele não reconhece.
$buscarcep->busca('Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu') -> Reconhece

$cepConsulta = 'Rua diadema Foz do Iguaçu';
$buscarcep->busca($cepConsulta) -> Não reconhece

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes Tem como nos passar exatamente o código que está testando quando utilizando a variável? Pode jogá-lo no Pastebin, Ideone, o que desejar, e passar o link aqui.

Comment: Como eu disse, esta com problema de tratar o erros e dados de entrada, não estou sendo critico, só estou querendo dizer, você é o programador, o PHP e nem linguagem nenhum tem como adivinhar coisas se você como programador não programar para ele detectar. ;)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Atualizei a pergunta com meu código exatamente como esta aqui. Aqui esta o link: https://ideone.com/fork/sXozcO acho que esta correto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui funcionou perfeitamente da maneira que você fez, não alterei linha alguma o problema deve estar em outra parte, **não tem nenhuma relação** com entrar ou não em `$buscarcep->busca(...)`

O problema deve ser ou nos dados vindos do POST ou na resposta que **você não tratou** com o `$xpath->query('//*[@class="respostadestaque"]');`, se a página dos correios não encontrar o endereço então deve estar emitindo uma mensagem de erro, o qual você não capturou, o PHP **não tem como advinha** que uma página HTML esta informando um erro, a não ser que você o programe pra fazer isto, vamos por etapas:

### Primeira etapa

O mais importante de tudo, faça a checagem dos valores de entrada sempre:

```
if (empty($_POST['rua'])) {
   die('Você não informou a rua');
} else if (empty($_POST['cidade'])) {
   die('Você não informou a cidade');
}

$ruaP = $_POST['rua'];
$cidadeP = $_POST['cidade'];
$enderecoP = $ruaP.' '.$cidadeP;
```

> Nota: Em `$enderecoP = $ruaP.' '.$cidadeP;` parenteses não são necessários para concactenar, eles são necessários para isolar, tipo quando vai concactenar algo que exige diferentes "tratamentos" ou se vai concactenar "calculos" com "string" ou fazer "calculos em ordem"

Pronto isto deve ajudar a evitar falta de informações

### Segundo passo

O `print_r` não é para imprimir strings (apesar de funcionar) é para array, o print_r também não reconhece valores booleanos, o teu script deve estar retornando `false` (false e true são booleanos) devido a isto:

```
// Se não encontrar CEP, retorna false
if (!$values->length) {
    return false;
}
```

Então troque por `var_dump`, pois o var_Dump "depura" tuas variaveis dizendo o tipo e o valor:

```
$dados = $buscarcep->busca($enderecoP);
var_dump($dados);
```

### Terceiro passo

Checar se houve um erro na resposta da página dos correios, como eu disse o PHP não é adivinho, você deve fazer o comportamento como humano e programar o PHP para fazer isto, por exemplo eu abri o http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do e digitei palavras aleatórias sem sentido e obtive a página de erro, a página dos correios no view-source do HTML retornou isto:

```
<div class="erro">
            Dados nao encontrados         <br>
        </div>
```

Então basta ajustar para isto:

```
$checkError = $xpath->query('//*[@class="erro"]');

if ($checkError->length) {
    return trim($checkError->item(0)->nodeValue);
}

$values = $xpath->query('//*[@class="respostadestaque"]');
$result = [];

// Se não encontrar CEP, retorna false
if (!$values->length) {
    throw new \Exception('CEP não encontrado');
}
```

Você também pode converter pra uma `Exception`, algo como:

```
$checkError = $xpath->query('//*[@class="erro"]');

if ($checkError->length) {
    throw new \Exception(trim($checkError->item(0)->nodeValue));
}
```

### Etapa extra

Um detalhe extra o Xpath `//*[@class="erro"]` não funciona bem para classes (atributo `class="..."`), por exemplo ele irá funcionar com:

Mas não irá funcionar com:

```
<div class="class1 class2 respostadestaque class4" ...
```

Então o Xpath mais apropriado seria este:

```
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ' . $classname . ' ")]
```

### Etapa extra 2 a decodificação

Assim como eu expliquei [*nesta resposta*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635) os documentos podem ser salvos como utf-8, neste caso é provável que os dados de entrada vindo por strings ou POST/GET acabam sendo utf-8, no caso pelo que o Anderson notou, a página não suporta "acentos", mas no caso deve ser somente acentos em "unicode", se tiver certeza que teus script estiverem em utf-8 então deve usar `utf8_decode`:

```
 $dados = $buscarcep->busca(utf8_decode($enderecoP));
```

Se os teus scripts PHP estivere usando ANSI e iso-8859-1 então não é necessário:

```
 $dados = $buscarcep->busca($enderecoP);
```

### Resultado final

Deve ficar mais ou menos assim

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['rua'])) {
   die('Você não informou a rua');
} else if (empty($_POST['cidade'])) {
   die('Você não informou a cidade');
}

$ruaP = $_POST['rua'];
$cidadeP = $_POST['cidade'];
$enderecoP = $ruaP . ' ' . $cidadeP;

class BuscaCEP
{
    private static function classSelector($classname) {
        return '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ' . $classname . ' ")]';
    }

    protected function formata($response)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($response);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $checkError = $xpath->query(self::classSelector('erro'));

        if ($checkError->length) {
            throw new \Exception(trim($checkError->item(0)->nodeValue));
        }

        $values = $xpath->query(self::classSelector('respostadestaque'));
        $result = [];

        // Se não encontrar CEP, retorna false
        if (!$values->length) {
            throw new \Exception('CEP não encotrado');
        }

        // Obtém informações desejadas, tratando-as quando necessário
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $result[] = preg_replace(
                '~[\s]{2,}~',
                '',
                trim($value->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue)
            );
        }

        list($logradouro, $bairro, $localidade, $cep) = $result;
        list($localidade, $uf) = explode('/', $localidade);

        return compact('logradouro', 'bairro', 'localidade', 'uf', 'cep');
    }

    public function busca($cep)
    {
        $response = file_get_contents(
            'http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do',
            false,
            stream_context_create([
                'http' => [
                    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query([
                        'cepEntrada' => $cep,
                        'metodo' => 'buscarCep',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        );

        return $this->formata($response);
    }
}

try {
    $buscarcep = new BuscaCEP();
    $dados = $buscarcep->busca(utf8_encode($enderecoP));
    echo $dados['bairro'];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump('Erro:', $e->getMessage()); //Exibe erro
}
```

Se teus scripts estiverem salvos em ANSI (provavelmente iso-8859-1/windows-1252):

```
try {
    $buscarcep = new BuscaCEP();
    $dados = $buscarcep->busca($enderecoP);
    echo $dados['bairro'];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump('Erro:', $e->getMessage()); //Exibe erro
}
```

Comment: O problema é a codificação dos valores. Como ele está utilizando "Foz de Iguaçu", o sistema não encontra o resultado, enquanto "Foz de Iguacu" (com C) funciona ou corrigindo a codificação.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso é só mais um dos **muitos erros** no script, a página dos correios deve usar ISO-8859-1 e não entende unicode, vou verificar, mas eu tenho um script para remover acentos e já deve resolver.

Comment: Exato. No código dele, só fazendo `$buscarcep->busca(utf8_decode($endereco01))` já faz funcionar, mas você entende melhor os detalhes de codificação melhor que eu xD

Comment: Gente, realmente não sei como agradecer. Eu estava focando em outros lados e não me toquei que poderia ser isso. Te agradeço muito @GuilhermeNascimento e Anderson Carlos Woss  por me ajudarem!!!!

Comment: Agora quem pode postar a resposta pra que eu possa dar confirmar como resposta correta?