# PHP colocar um simbolo carinha.jpeg dentro de um <select> e gravar a carinha.jpeg selecionado em campo do banco de dados mysql e exibir no cliente

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, select, upload

tenho uma tabela que gera 5 colunas, queria colocar dentro de uma TD um select e dentro do Select colocar 5 imagens padrão ( tipo emojis do whats mas em jpeg ) indicando a presença / status da pessoa. Só que não sei nem por onde começar. 
A tabela no BD eu já fiz, chama-se clientes e quero inserir esta imagem no campo presenca,  e a TD que quero incluir chama-se presenca.
Isto para fazer um UPDATE no tabela clientes.

```
        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Hora</th>
                                <th>Dra</th>
                                <th>Codigo Paciente</th>                                
                                <th>Paciente</th>
                                <th>Plano</th>
                                <th>Contato</th>    
                                <th>Presenca</th>                                   
                                <th>Fazer</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td align "center" ><?php echo $rows_cursos['hora'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['codigo_dentista'];?></td>
        <td align "center" ><?php echo $rows_cursos['codigo_paciente']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['plano'];?></td>                                        
        <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['celular'];?></td>                                  
        <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['presenca'];?></td>... 
...
```

Comment: Pode ser em HTML também

Comment: Fora usar o `utf8mb4` no seu banco de dados também é necessário salvar os teus .php como "utf-8 sem bom" e ajustar a conexão, fora adicionar o header com charset, veja mais detalhes em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, na verdade a pagina ( apenas para consultas internas ) já funciona apenas foi requerido que insira os emojis no status. Então preciso no Insert colocar os emojis e na view que eles apareçam para o usuário, atualizando a cada 10 minutos.