# Como corrigir charset="UTF-8" em aplicação nodejs dentro do socket.io

Tags: node.js, utf-8, socket.io

Tenho uma aplicação de um chat e estou trabalhando com `nodejs` e `socket.io`. Porém estou tendo problemas com a codificação de nomes. O seguinte nome: **Guilherme Loução** está vindo como: **Guilherme LouÃ§Ã£o**. Já salvei o arquivo com o formato UTF-8 e não resolveu. Existe alguma módulo para corrigir isso dentro do socket.io?

**Código:**

```
...
io.sockets.on('connection', ioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret,
  timeout: 15000
})).on('authenticated', function(socket) {

  socket.on('join', function(data){

    console.log(data.name);
  });
  ...
});
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua página deve estar usando iso-8859-1/windows-1252 e a resposta JSON retorna em utf-8, você pode mudar a página (ou add-on) para usar o:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Também é necessário [salvar os documentos (se tiver algum, como `.html` ou templates) como UTF-8 sem BOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8/43205#43205).

No entanto se deseja usar iso-8859-1 você pode tentar decodificar de utf-8, primeiro instale isto via *npm*:

```
npm install utf8
```

Depois chame assim:

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');
```

Então use:

```
console.log( utf8.decode(data.name) );
```