# Charset não funciona no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho a seguinte função JavaScript que emite um `confirm` com uma mensagem que contém caracteres especiais.

```
function cancelaCadastro(){
    var cancelaCadastro = confirm(unescape("Você deseja cancelar o cadastro e voltar à página inicial?"));
    if (cancelaCadastro == true){
        location.href= "index.php";
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

O problema é que a mensagem está sendo exibida da seguinte forma.
"Voc� deseja cancelar o cadastro e voltar � p�gina inicial?".

Coloquei o `unescape` para tentar corrigir esse erro, mas não foi eficaz.
Informo que na página HTML já defini o `charset` para `utf-8` e para `ISO`, mas também não resolveu o problema.
Segue exemplo do `meta-charset`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
```

OBS: Essa pergunta não é uma duplicata da pergunta [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8), pois o problema não é relacionado a utilizar 2 tipos de charset diferentes.
De qualquer forma, defini o charset da página pelo php utilizando a linha de código `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>`
 e também salvei a página como HTML sem BOM, mas o problema não foi resolvido.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: Amigo a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 explica exatamente que é impossivel usar 2 charsets, na verdade a resposta ensina como configurar um charset unico especifico, você não deve salvar só a página com "UT8 sem BOM", mas os arquivos `.js` também devem ser salvos com "UTF8 sem bom". Leia a resposta com calma e vai entender, ela é um guia de como fazer.

Comment: Guilherme, salvei todos arquivos .js em UTF8 sem BOM, mas continua do mesmo jeito.
Peço que verifique o comentário que fiz na resposta do Mateus Calixto. Talvez as informações que coloquei nesse comentário ajudem a identificar o problema.

Comment: Na resposta e nem no comentário eu disse que o problema é unicamente salvar os .php e .js como UTF-8, eu disse que este é um dos detalhes, tem que seguir o passo a passo e fazer  todos, pode ser que com um header da vida já resolva, mas vc vai rodar os resultados em um local diferente e na verdade você irá causar um efeito colateral inimaginável, o melhor possivel é revisar todos os pontos, header, html, mysql charset, salvar os documentos com utf8 incluindo os que estão como include e etc. A resposta explica bem isto. Não é pq um header funcionou de primeira que vc está garantido ;)

Comment: Outra coisa, você tem que ver se de fato você quer usar UTF-8 ou iso-8859-1 e assim ajustar conforme o desejado, se for iso-8859-1 (ou latin1 no banco) então basta trocar o utf-8 por iso-8859-1 e salvar os documentos como ANSI, fora claro setar o header. A resposta lá só usou o utf-8 de exemplo, não quer dizer que vc é obrigado a usar UTF-8 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione esse código no cabeçalho do arquivo index do PHP;

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true) ?>
```

Aguardo resultados.

Comment: Adicionei o código proposto mas não resolveu o problema.
Já salvei o arquivo em UTF-8 com BOM e sem BOM. Também já defini o charset de todos os scripts para UTF-8.

Não sei se tem alguma coisa a ver, mas quando fiz o código PHP que pegava o valor dos inputs das páginas e atribuía para uma variável , precisei utilizar o "utf8_decode" nas variáveis para garantir que os registros fossem feitos sem erros de caracteres. Existe alguma forma de dar um decode geral na página?

Comment: OBS: Verifiquei que o problema não ocorre no Firefox, mas ocorro no google chrome.

Comment: Na onde você está colocando esse código que passei, em qual arquivo, index.php?

Comment: Coloquei na página que estou implementando o JavaScript, se trata de uma página de cadastro e sua extensão é .php .

Comment: Acabei de colocar o código que você passou na index.php e deu certo! Muito obrigado Mateus!

Comment: De nada, era pra colocar na index.php mesmo kkk! qualquer coisa estamos aqui, pode colocar minha resposta como solução?

Comment: Acabei de colocar sua resposta como solução, obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o atributo `charset` na declaração do script.
Exemplo:

```
<script charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: Não resolveu, amigo.

Comment: @HugoGuitti Qual editor/IDE você está utilizando para codificar? Recomendo mudar a codificação do arquivo no editor/IDE utilizado e em seguida salvar as alterações.

Comment: Estou usando o SublimeText. O arquivo foi salvo em UTF-8 sem BOM.

Answer (score -3):

No CSS: `<style> html:lang(pt-br) { @charset "UTF-8"; } </style>`

No HTML:  `<html lang="pt-br">`

No HEAD:  `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

No JavaScript - exemplo:  `<script src="javascript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

Dessa forma funciona quando uso o charset UTF-8 no CSS3 junto com PHP 7.3, junto com JavaScript e junto com o Bootstrap 4.3.1