# Retorno de "?" ao invés dos caracteres especiais em um SELECT

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou com um problema, já codifiquei tudo com utf-8, tentei de múltiplas maneiras arrumar isso e não consigo, em um `<option>` do HTML, eu puxo uma tabela do banco de dados, mas a mesma retorna com um símbolo de caracteres especiais ao invés dos acentos como na foto abaixo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código do `<select>` é ésse

```
<select id="modalidade" name="modalidade" class="form-control">
        <?php
            header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
            //require_once ('../model/Conexao.php');
            //mysql_set_charset('utf8');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM modalidade";
            $cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "olimpiada");
            $resultado = mysqli_query($cnx,$sql,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
            $qtde = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

            if($qtde>0)
            {
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
                {

                    echo "<option value=".$linha['idModalidade'].">";
                    echo $linha['modalidade'];
                    echo "</option>";

                }
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

Aqui está a estrutura do banco de dados
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já

Comment: O projeto está configurado como utf-8 também?

Comment: Só pra constar , o `header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");` deveria estar antes de qualquer HTML, você colocou no meio do HTML, isto não sabe reconhecer, a não ser que use ob_start (o que pode ser um uso exagerado sem necessidade), ainda sim o melhor é organizar os headers acima de tudo e antes de qualquer output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa a função do **PHP** `utf8_encode()`, `utf8_encode($linha['modalidade']);`

Ou altera sua tabela no banco para `SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Olá Henrique, *não leve a mal*, o autor da pergunta já usa utf8mb4, não tem sentido algum usar `SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` e o uso de `utf8_encode` neste caso esta mais para um remendo, é algo que funciona sim, mas ainda pode ter outros problemas, recomendo que você pesquise antes, este tipo de pergunta já foi feito pelo menos umas 20 vezes, vou lhe citar só um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, pois o autor esta tendo problemas com a codificação, ao invés de chutar uma resposta, pesquise se já existe uma boa resposta e marque como duplicata. ;)

Comment: Cara, eu não chutei nada. Só disse a ele o que eu ja fiz pra resolver isso. Remendo ou não, resolveu. Tanto que aceitaram a resposta. Agora, se você tem uma resposta melhor. Coloca aí, eu vou ler e vou aprender com sua resposta, o autor provavelmente vai fazer o mesmo... Melhor do que ficar tentando dar lição com "não me leve a mal" ou "chutar resposta".

Comment: Não estou dando lição estou lhe orientando, fui educado contigo, lhe expliquei o motivo e os problemas, gastei um tempo aqui, o mínimo que você deve fazer é tentar presumir boa intenção quando alguém está tentando lhe orientar ao invés de ficar pensando que é um ataque pessoal. Como eu já disse essa pergunta do autor é uma duplicata e antes de responder você deveria ter pesquisado no site se já haviam perguntas similares com respostas e usar o botão "Sinalizar" para marcar com duplicata. Estamos todos aqui para aprender, vc pode aprender mais se pesquisar também ;)