# Problemas com UTF-8 em revenda LocaWeb

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um projeto hospedado na locaweb na revenda, o php/html estão codificados corretamente em utf-8, pois oque é html ou echo esta retornando perfeitamente, porem informações vindas do banco não são retornadas corretamente com ç,á,é...

Via HeidiSQL já tentei diversos procedimentos de ALTER TABLE para utf8 e general_ci, porem nenhum foi concluída com sucesso, via Heidi posso observar que existem dois tipos de informação das variaveis a SESSION e a GLOBAL, SESSION esta correta com utf8, porem a GLOBAL esta como latin1 e latin1_swedish_ci.

As informações são trazidas via PDO e o banco é MySQL.

Resumo, não é o PHP (tudo possível já foi testado) e também não é o meta do HTML.

Pergunta:

Como modificar para que as informações venham em utf8 corretamente sem a gambiarra do utf8_encode ?

Existe alguma maneira de trocar as informações do mysql, como fazemos com o php.ini na locaweb ?

Comment: Siga o passo-a-passo, veja todos os detalhes, algo deve ter ficado faltando: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, tudo feito conforme indicado em sua resposta a outra pergunta. Nada foi modificado, todos os passos foram repetidos por mim exatamente como indicados.
Estão funcionando os acentos e demais, porem não funciona quando é pego via o banco de dados, e ele esta setado como indicado utf8, porem somente na Session e não no Global (visualizado via heidi).

Comment: Deve ter esquecido algo, posta o que tem por favor. PS: Eu uso locaweb.

Comment: Após todos os jeitos serem aplicados, após um delay começou a funcionar.. Não imagino o porque.. Mas deu tudo certo (:
Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ser cache.

Answer (score -1):

Tente configurar o `PDO` para `UTF-8` na criação da conexão:

```
conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$host.'; dbname='.$db,
    $user,
    $senha,
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);
```

Comment: Coloquei "$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));".. mas nada mudou.