# Codificação do Form

Tags: php, html

Tenho um form em uma página que contém a seguinte **`tag`** no head

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

O **`form`** tá apontado para a página **`processa.php`** e no topo dessa página também coloquei a **`tag`** `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Acontece que os emails que estou recebendo dessa página **`processa.php`** estão todos com acentuação errada, já fiz várias alterações e tudo está igual. o que pode ser?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8/43205#43205

Comment: Não @13dev. Se ele usar BOM vai ficar muito pior, porque são bytes que não aparecem em nenhum editor de texto. Só vai aparecer uma grande linha em branco no início do código HTML se visto através de um browser. O ideal é salvar `UTF-8 Without BOM` (codificação UTF-8 sem marcadores de byte). O Notepad++ tem essa opção, só baixar, instalar, abrir os arquivos e ir em `Format` e marcar essa opção.

Comment: toda razão @TonyMontana queria escrever `without` mas obrigado pela informação, o sublime também oferece essa opção

Comment: O que está usando para enviar esses emails na pagina processa.php?

Comment: eu tive um problema parecido e resolvi assim: na página header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", true);  E na parte do envio  $mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';

Answer (score 0):

Caso este código abaixo não funcionar:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", true);
```

Talvez seja necessário você utilizar um outro recurso do php que faz com que a variável seja codificada isoladamente.

Ex.

```
$nome = utf8_encode($_POST['nome']);
```

Caso não funcione tenta isso:

```
$nome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
```

Se nenhum desses dois funcionarem, especifique qual a biblioteca sendmail você está utilizando em php.

Se for phpMailer você pode resolver assim:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

Abraços!