# Os acentos da minha página não aparecem?

Tags: html

Criei uma página *html*, no entanto os acentos não estão sendo lidos, já testei o seguinte código mas não funciona.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

O que faço posso fazer então?

Comment: Poste seu <head> para dar pra verificar o problema melhor.

Comment: Relacionada / Possível Duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/66203).

Answer (score 9):

Tudo depende de como os caracteres estão sendo gravados e carregados
Se ao invés de *Coração*, ele exibe **Cora��o** ou **CoraÃ§Ã£o**.
No primeiro caso **Cora��o**, sua página em **ISO-8859-1** está obtendo a palavra Coração armazenada em **UTF-8** da origem, seja ela do banco de dados ou de um XML, txt etc.
Já o segundo caso (**CoraÃ§Ã£o**) é a sua página em **UTF-8** exibindo a palavra Coração armazenada em **ISO-8859-1** da origem.

Pode colocar a codificação dentro do meta assim:

Para ISO-8859-1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Minha pagina</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Para UTF-8:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Minha pagina</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

E pode também colocar codificação html para os acentos, segue a lista:

```
Tabela com os caracteres mais utilizados
A maiúsculo com acento agudo    Á   &Aacute;
E maiúsculo com acento agudo    É   &Eacute;
I maiúsculo com acento agudo    Í   &Iacute;
O maiúsculo com acento agudo    Ó   &Oacute;
U maiúsculo com acento agudo    Ú   &Uacute;
A minúsculo com acento agudo    á   &aacute;
E minúsculo com acento agudo    é   &eacute;
I minúsculo com acento agudo    í   &iacute;
O minúsculo com acento agudo    ó   &oacute;
U minúsculo com acento agudo    ú   &uacute;
A maiúsculo com acento circunflexo  Â   &Acirc;
E maiúsculo com acento circunflexo  Ê   &Ecirc;
O maiúsculo com acento circunflexo  Ô   &Ocirc;
A minúsculo com acento circunflexo  â   &acirc;
E minúsculo com acento circunflexo  ê   &ecirc;
O minúsculo com acento circunflexo  ô   &ocirc;
A maiúsculo com crase   À   &Agrave;
A minúsculo com crase   à   &agrave;
U maiúsculo com trema   Ü   &Uuml;
U minúsculo com trema   ü   &uuml;
C cedilha maiúsculo Ç   &Ccedil;
C cedilha minúsculo ç   &ccedil;
A com til maiúsculo Ã   &Atilde;
O com til maiúsculo Õ   &Otilde;
A com til minúsculo ã   &atilde;
O com til minúsculo õ   &otilde;
N com til maiúsculo Ñ   &Ntilde;
N com til minúsculo ñ   &ntilde;
E comercial &   &amp;
Aspa dupla  "   &quot;
Aspa simples    '   &#039;
Menor que   <   &lt;
Maior que   >   &gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ÁÀÃÂ</h1>
    <body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

## ÁÀÃÂ

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja usando o HTML 5 sem saber, essa é a diferença entre os dois:

```
<!-- HTML 4 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!-- HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Tente com a forma do HTML 5.