# Windows com php os caracteres utf-8 estão corretos e no Linux não?

Tags: php, mysql

Criei páginas em php no ambiente windows 2012 com php (para migrar do asp para php)

As páginas em php são:

HTML5 (feitas no Notpad++ em Codificação UTF-8)

Tem `< meta charset="UTF-8" >` nos head

Acessos no Mysql: `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxx.mysql.dbaas.com.br;dbname=xxx; charset=utf8", "login", "senha")`

campos nas tabelas = `latin1_general_ci`

**RESULTADO:** Acentuação e caracteres perfeitos nos dados do Mysql e textos nas páginas.

**PROBLEMA no php Linux**:

Transferi as mesmas páginas para o Linux e acessando o MESMO BD Mysql

E deu ERRO NA ACENTUAÇÃO:

Dados do Mysql com ERRO e outros textos nas páginas correto

**COMPLEMENTO**

Neste meio tempo:
Troquei a versão para php 7.1
criei uma tabela no Mysql do Linux
E a acentuação está correta.

Considero encerrado este assunto.

Comment: Veja se resolve [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193)

Comment: Há alguns meses, eu usei estas orientações para criar as pag.php e deu tudo certo. Estou intrigado porque é OK no Windows 2012 com php e com erro no php puro. Será que o windows/php tem configuração diferente? Não temos acesso na Locaweb. Obrigado.

Comment: Não tentei. Vou baixar estes 2 e fazer uns testes. O que gostei no Notepad é um app de FTP que transfere ao salvar o arquivo. É bem prático. Valeu a dica !!!

Comment: Atom, Sublime e Visual Studio não rodam no Windows Vista. Tentei agora.

Comment: Deve ser porque o Linux é melhor que o ruindows ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui corrigir a acentuação:

> Mysql Tabela: colocar em Collation = utf8_unicode_ci

Conexão ao BD com PDO

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX; charset=utf8", "XX", "XX", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Obs: Este array corrigiu os erros de acentuação.

E agora estão corretos os textos em html e os dados do BD.

Comment: Atualizei para PHP 7.1 e as pag que eu NÃO coloquei o array acima, SE MOSTRARAM PERFEITAS NAS ACENTUAÇÕES. Parece que o 7.1 acertou a compatibilidade de  charset. Surpresa boa !!!

Comment: O `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` é o mesmo que o `$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`, só que auto-executado.