# Como resolver esse error de acentuação: �

Tags: php, html

Olá! Estou usando `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >` no meu meu HTML mas não está resolvendo esse error aqui: � .
O banco de dados está com acentos, como posso resolver esse error?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8

Comment: Como consta na resposta da pergunta linkada como duplicata, verifique se seu editor de códigos também está em UTF-8.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma: utf8_encode
Vlw, pessoal.