# Coletando palavras de um input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma página (apenas para estudo) de uma livraria. A variável `titulo_livro` recebe os dados de um `input type='text'`.

O que preciso fazer:

O título do livro muitas das vezes conterá mais de uma palavra. Como faço para coletar essas palavras, exemplo ("O","Acopolato","Odisseu") e buscá-las no banco de dados?

A idéia da busca é, ao digitar o titulo completo do livro, o retorno do BD pode ser por quaisquer uma das palavras digitadas, já que as palavras ("O","Acopolato","Odisseu") poderiam, separadamente, estarem no título de algum outro livro.

Comment: WHERE COLUNA LIKE '%O%' OR COLUNA LIKE '%Acopolato%' OR .......

Comment: Vc vai ter que separar as palavras no PHP e fazer uma query com critérios no BD.

Comment: Certo, compreendi. Mas para isso, cada palavra deve estar salva em uma coluna separada no BD, certo? Mas não está assim...titulo_livro é uma unica coluna contendo todo o titulo do livro...dados os fatos, seria possível?

Comment: Utilizando `LIKE '%palavra%'` localiza a palavra estando no começo, meio ou fim do valor da coluna. Utilizando `LIKE 'palavra%'` localiza apenas no começo e `LIKE '%palavra'` localiza apenas no fim. É possível também fazer combinações, por exemplo localizar quando tem as duas palavras separadas `LIKE '%palavra%outra%'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar `LIKE` e `OR` na query e `preg_split` (equivalente ao `explode`, mas poderá isolar mais espaços sem necessitar de filtrar) no PHP para dividir a string:

```
if (isset($_POST['busca']{0})) { //Tem que ter digita ao menos uma letra
    $buscas = preg_split('#\s+#', $_POST['busca']);

    ... aqui vai o código mysql, podendo usar a API PDO ou MSYQLI ...
}
```

Se o formulário for POST use `$_POST['busca']`, se não use `$_GET['busca']`

> **Nota:** se estiver usando UTF-8 leia esta postagem: [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

---

### Usando com MYSQLI

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('SERVIDOR', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA', 'BANCO');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['busca']{0})) {

    $buscas = preg_split('#\s+#', $_POST['busca']);

    $qtdPalavras = count($buscas);

    //Gera os LIKEs
    $where = str_repeat('nome LIKE ? OR ', $qtdPalavras);
    $where = substr($where, 0, -4); // Remove o OR extra

    $query = 'SELECT id, nome, data FROM livros WHERE ' . $where . ' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 100';

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt) {

        //Adiciona os tipos de parâmetros
        array_unshift($buscas, str_repeat('s', $qtdPalavras));
        $qtdPalavras++;//Atualiza o total

        for ($i = 0; $i < $qtdPalavras; $i++) {

            //Evita adicionar o sinal de porcentagem no primeiro item, que são os tipos de parâmetros
            if ($i > 0) {

                //O sinal de porcentagem é necessário para busca em qualquer posição
                $buscas[$i] = '%' . $buscas[$i] . '%';
            }

            //Passa o valor como referencia (& - E comercial), pois bind_param não aceita variáveis normais
            $buscas[$i] = &$buscas[$i];
        }

        //Chava os valores da array como parametros
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $buscas);

        //Executa
        $stmt->execute();

        //Vá adicionando as colunas aqui que necessitar
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $nome, $ano);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo 'Nome:', $nome, '<br>';
            echo 'Ano:', $ano, '<hr>';
        }

        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        die('Erro:' . $mysqli->error);
    }
}
```

A query conforme a busca irá gerar em um POST como `"O Acopolato Odisseu"` algo como:

```
SELECT id, nome, ano FROM livros WHERE nome LIKE ? OR nome LIKE ? OR nome LIKE ? ORDER BY nome LIMIT 100
```

Os interrogações recebem os valores do `bind_param` e no banco será executado algo como:

```
SELECT id, nome, ano FROM livros WHERE nome LIKE '%O%' OR nome LIKE '%Acopolato%' OR nome LIKE '%Odisseu%' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 100
```

---

### Usando com PDO

Se for PDO deve ficar algo semelhante a isto:

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=SERVIDOR;dbname=BANCO', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

if (isset($_POST['busca']{0})) {

    $buscas = preg_split('#\s+#', $_POST['busca']);

    $qtdPalavras = count($buscas);

    //Gera os LIKEs
    $where = str_repeat('nome LIKE ? OR ', $qtdPalavras);
    $where = substr($where, 0, -4); // Remove o OR extra

    $sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, nome, data FROM livros WHERE ' . $where . ' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 100');

    if ($sth) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $qtdPalavras; $i++) {
           $buscas[$i] = '%' . $buscas[$i] . '%';
        }

        $response = $sth->execute($buscas);

        if ($response) {
            while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo 'Nome:', $row['nome'], '<br>';
                echo 'Ano:', $row['data'], '<hr>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Erro: ';
            var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, já estou tentando aqui! Muito obrigado. Logo menos posto os resultados.

Comment: @LucasNeves tinha alguns erros no mysqli, já corrigi, também adicionei algumas explicações sobre utf-8 ou iso-8859-1 e também corrigi um problema no exemplo com PDO. Teste todos, basta adaptar agora ao seu.

Comment: Boa tarde! Adaptei ao meu código.

Deu este erro:

Warning: preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_repeate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php on line 13

Comment: O FORM:
<form method="post" action="visualizaEmprestimo2.php" class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <select type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="ativo">
      <option>Selecione...</option>
      <option value="1">Ativo</option>
      <option value="0">Inativo</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título Livro" name="titulo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Consultar">
    </div>
   </form>

Comment: @Lucas por isso te mandei a mensagem, eu já corrigi, foi a 4 horas atrás que fiz as correções, copia novamente os códigos, eu revisei eles e testei, agora estão ok ;)

Comment: Acabei de alterar meu brother! Infelizmente, o erro persiste:

Warning: preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php on line 42

Comment: @LucasNeves olha a linha 42, esta exatamente assim `preg_split('#\s+#',...` ?

Comment: Agooora está! E deu certo! Mas ainda persiste um erro..será que consegue decifrar?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_repeate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dunevera\visualizaEmprestimo2.php on line 45

Comment: @LucasNeves esse erro é da primeira versão do script que eu fiz, basta copiar novamente o código acima, porque o código antigo estava com muitos problemas. Qual vc esta usando? Com pdo ou mysqli?

Comment: Meu amigo, muito obrigado pela atenção e pela paciência. Está tudo funcionando perfeitamente agora. Grande abraço e feliz natal!

OBS: como sou novo por aqui, não presumi de primeira que precisava clicar em 'editada' para ver o novo texto editado, kkkk. Erro de usuário. kkkk

Comment: feliz natal @LucasNeves, e se puder marcar a resposta como aceita eu ficaria grato, se não souber como fazer leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635

Answer (score 1):

Conforme dito no comentário `WHERE COLUNA LIKE '%O%' OR COLUNA LIKE '%Acopolato%' OR .......`

**Com PDO**

```
if (isset($_POST['nameInput'])){

  //verifica se só contém espaços
  if (trim($_POST['nameInput'])===''){

    echo "<span style=\"font-size: 24px; color: red\";>nananicanão, só espaço vazio não pode</span>";

  }else{

  $input = $_POST['nameInput'];

  //Substituindo vários espaços por um único espaço
  $titulo_livro= preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);

    $hostname="localhost";  
    $username="USUARIO";  
    $password="SENHA";  
    $db = "NOME_DB"; 

    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

    $titulo_livro = strtoupper($titulo_livro);
    //Retira as tags HTML e PHP
    $titulo_livro = strip_tags($titulo_livro); 
    //Retira espaço no ínicio e final
    $titulo_livro = trim($titulo_livro);
    $words = explode(' ', $titulo_livro);

    $words_condition = array();
    $arguments = array();

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $words_condition[] = 'nomeColuna LIKE ?';
        $arguments[] = '%'.$word.'%';
    }

    $query = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM nomeTabela WHERE '.implode(' OR ', $words_condition));

    $query->execute($arguments);

    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {

        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           //o que quer retornar relacione aqui
           echo 'Titulo:', $row['nomeColuna'], '<hr>';
        }
    }else{
       echo "<span style=\"font-size: 24px; color: red\";>Sua busca não retornou resultados</span>";
    }
  }
}
```

**com MYSQLI**

Podemos construir a declaração da seguinte forma

```
//conexão
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USUARIO";
$password = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME_DB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//pego via POST
$titulo_livro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, Trim($_POST['nameInput']));

$palavras = explode(" ", $titulo_livro);

$clausulaWhere = '';
foreach( $palavras as $palavra) {
   $clausulaWhere .= ' nomeColuna LIKE "%' . $palavra . '%" OR';
}

// Remove ultimo 'OR'
$clausulaWhere = substr($clausulaWhere, 0, -2);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nomeTabela WHERE" . $clausulaWhere;

//echo $sql; 
//para $titulo_livro = "O copolato Odisseu" resulta
// SELECT * FROM nomeTabela WHERE nomeColuna LIKE "%O%" OR nomeColuna LIKE "%copolato%" OR nomeColuna LIKE "%Odisseu%"


$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo  $row["nomeColuna"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo. Mas estou utilizando PDO.

Comment: @LucasNeves, é que na pergunta vc não especificou esse detalhe. Adicionei PDO na minha resposta!

Comment: Curiosidade, pq está editando todas suas respostas em massa desse jeito?

Comment: @Articuno, estou retirando os exemplos funcionais

Comment: Por que? Retirando vc n descaracteriza as respostas?

Comment: @Articuno, não descaracteriza, aliás, alguns arquivos não existem mais ou foram editados, mesma coisa com os que dependem do banco de dados, algumas tabelas não existem mais. E para as pessoas clicarem nos exemplos funcionais e darem de cara com erro, estou retirando.