# problema ao alterar variavel de ambiente PHP

Tags: php, oracle, apache

instalei o php via xampp e preciso alterar essa variavel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

NSL_LANG.

criei um arquivo php com esse código:

```
<?php 

putenv("NLS_LANG=BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252") or die("Falha ao inserir a variavel de ambiente");

phpinfo();

?>
```

mas quando abro essa pagina ele mostra como na imagem.

Eu preciso alterar essa variável de ambiente para essa da função. Alguem sabe como faz isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que pelo tempo de execução isso não vai funcionar, isto porque quando executa o `putenv` o cliente Oracle já esta rodando, e se eu não estiver enganado, a comunicação do PHP com o cliente Oracle é "paralela" e não no mesmo "contexto", ou seja usar `putenv` não vai afetar o processo do cliente oracle.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar manualmente, no windows faça isto:

<kbd>Computador</kbd> > <kbd>Propriedades</kbd> > <kbd>Configurações avançadas do sistema</kbd>

Irá aparecer uma janela semelhante a esta:

[image: propriedades do sistema]

Então clique em *Variaveis de ambiente* e depois em <kbd>Novo...</kbd>, assim:

[image: nova variavel de ambiente]

Se for usar o cliente oracle em mais de um usuário use o `variaveis de sistema` (é preferivel), se for usar somente no usuário atual e deseja realmente restringir a isto então selecione o "novo" do "Variaveis de usuário para ".

No campo nome da variavel adicione `NLS_LANG`
No campo valor da variavel adicione `BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252`

Depois disto talvez seja necessário fazer LOGOFF ou até mesmo reiniciar o Windows.

---

### Usando Apache e PHP

Note que aplicar `NLS_LANG=BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252` só vai afetar o cliente oracle, isto não vai afetar as APIs para banco do PHP e nem o Apache, pois o charset do apache assim como o INPUT que vem de forms ou até mesmo como salvou os scripts `.php` podem estar em uma codificação diferente.

O `BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252` equivale ao windows-1252, que é equivalente ao iso-8859-1, e como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 você deve utilizar:

- PHP scripts salvos em "iso-8859-1" (ou windows-1252 e ANSI)
- Preferencialmente defina usando PHP `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

Primeiro deve salvar "todos scripts .php" como iso-8859-1 (ou ANSI) e documentos .html (se houver):

- Para salvar usando notepad++:

  [image: salvando documento em ANSI com notepad++]
- Para salvar usando SublimeText:

  [image: salvando documento em iso-8859-1 ou windows 1252]

> **Nota:** creio que **não é necessário** definir no `oci_connect` o charset, pois ele já assume o charset definido em `NSLANG`, mas acaso não funcione tente assim:
>
> ```
> $db = ocilogon($user, $pass, $connectString, 'WE8MSWIN1252');
> ```