# DIferença de lang e meta charset em html

Tags: html, html5

Estou com dúvida de qual a diferença entre as definições `<meta lang="pt-br">` e `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: Lang é somente para especificar para BOTs e afins qual o idioma provavel do site, ou seja é para facilitar, já charset é para definir a codificação que a págian usa, tipo iso-8859-1 ou utf-8 (existem outras). Ambas não tem relação alguma.

Comment: Charset é tipo uma abreviação de "character set" ou seja, "conjunto de caracteres" o UTF8 engloba um grupo imenso de Characteres https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 caracteres que pode ser usados em Inglês, Espanhol, PT-br :) etc..

Answer (score 9):

Ambos atributos não tem relação alguma, cada um tem um objetivo.

O atributo `lang=` é somente para especificar para BOTs e afins qual o idioma provavel da página ou de um elemento HTML especifico, por exemplo na mesma página:

```
<!-- irá informar que esta em português, independente de região -->
<p lang="pt">olá mundo</p>

<!-- irá informar que esta em inglês, independente de região -->
<p lang="en">Hello world</p>

<!-- irá informar que esta em português do Brasil -->
<p lang="pt-BR">olá mundo</p>

<!-- irá informar que esta em inglês britânico -->
<p lang="en-GB">Hello world</p>
```

Indica aos bots e afins que o primeiro `<p>` esta em português e o segundo em inglês, ou seja é para facilitar a vida dos BOTs (ou qualquer outro tipo de **software cliente**).

É claro que se definir na tag `<html lang="(idioma)">` para informar que a página toda esta em determinado idioma.

Já o atributo `charset=` usado na tag `<meta>`, assim:

```
<meta charset="(codificação escolhida)">
```

ou a meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=(codificação escolhida)">
```

Servem para definir a codificação que a página usa, tipo iso-8859-1 ou utf-8 (existem outras), o tipo de codificação não tem relação com idioma, mas sim com o sistema de carácteres que irá usar, e este mesmo sistema de caracteres pode ser usado por inúmeros idiomas, como é o caso do *utf-8*, note que o `charset` vai definir a página toda, ou seja você **não pode usar dois charsets na mesma página**, como expliquei nesta resposta:

- [**Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

Answer (score -3):

Meta tag content-language: ela é a responsável por identificar em qual idioma está escrito seu site. Geralmente, a identificação é feita por abreviações dos principais idiomas. Exemplo: en-us (inglês norte-americano); pt-br (português brasileiro).

já A tag meta charset="UTF-8" é uma tag meta utilizada para comunicar aos navegadores qual é o formato de codificação de caracteres utilizado naquele documento.
Em outras palavras, essa tag serve para que os navegadores saibam como devem renderizar os textos incluídos em uma página específica.cujo idioma contenha caracteres especiais sem a exibição de erros.

Comment: A documentação orienta a [não usar o elemento meta `content-language` para declarar o idioma do documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20this%20meta%20element%20like%20this%20for%20stating%20a%20document%20language) use o atributo global [lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) no documento ou partes dele.

Comment: Se procurar a norma [RFC 9110 na Seção 8.5. Content-Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#field.content-language) verá que o cabeçalho `Content-Language` descreve a linguagem nativa da audiência pretendida pelo documento, o que não significa e nem é o mesmo que identificar a linguagem na qual o documento está escrito.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).