# Retorno Json com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Estou realizando uma consulta na base de dados (Php, Mysql e Ajax), o retorno dessa consulta é um Json, no entanto todos os acentos estão vindo com caracteres especiais, coloquei um log para ver o resultado. Abaixo contém o código que preenche o meu array.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$query_somente_alunos_presentes);
$linhas=mysqli_num_rows($sql); 

if( $linhas > 0 ) {
    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $vetor[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
}    
    //Passando vetor em forma de json
    echo   json_encode($vetor);
}
```

Veja  log que sai na página:

Array(2)

```
0
:
{id: "1", nome: "TimÃ³teo da Silva", imagem: "TimÃ_1520692755.jpg"}
1
:
{id: "10", nome: "JoÃ£o Barretos", imagem: "JoÃ£o_1520689587.jpg"}
2
:
{id: "11", nome: "JoÃ£o Pedro", imagem: "JoÃ£o_1520689891.jpg"}
```

Ja tentei utilizar set caracters do mysql, utf8 de todos jeito ....

Comment: a pagina está usando o meta chartset com utf8? O dado salvo no banco já é utf8?

Comment: Sim os dados estão salvos no formato utf-8 e a página também.<meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: então não precisa fazer  conversão, no "array_map('utf8_encode'", acredito

Comment: Como eu faço sem a conversão?

Comment: @PauloGalego abre o arquivo e salva ele como utf-8, tenho certeza que se, seu banco e o arquivo estiverem no mesmo formato vai funcionar

Comment: $vetor[] =$resultado;

Comment: antes disso tem um passo ai, pois tem um loop que a cada volta insere os dados da variável $resultado dentro do $vetor[].

Comment: Julio, você mencionou que devo salvar o arquivo no formato utf-8, eu tenho aqui dois arquivos php, um para exibir os dados e o outro para processar as informações. qual desses devo efetuar esse procedimentos de salvar como utf-8?  E na opção salvar como não tem utf8.... perdoa a ignorancia minha

Comment: consegui!!! Isso resolveu mesmo $vetor[] =$resultado; Sveen!!!

Comment: O problema todo é que deve estar codificando algo já codificado, você basicamente esta programado orientado a sorte, com o perdão da palavra. Entenda que antes de criar algo você deve preparar o "ambiente todo" para a codificação desejada, não é porque algo esta funcionando que significa que esteja correto, esta resposta explica tudo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 - resumindo, você deve configurar os headers, banco e salvar todos .php com mesma codificação, se deixar algo para trás o problema poderá surgir no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

alterei apenas uma linha do código:

```
if( $linhas > 0 ) {
    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      //  $vetor[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
        $vetor[] =$resultado;  // <- apenas isso..
}    
    //Passando vetor em forma de json

    echo   json_encode($vetor);
}
```