# utf8 no ionic 2 visual studio 2017

Tags: ionic2

Já tentei de todas as formas colocar as strings com acento mas não adianta. As letras ficam com caracteres estranhos. Alguma sugestão? lang="pt-br" não funciona. Isso ocorre usando o visual studio.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: não resolveu. Estou usando o visual studio.

Comment: como está o formato do arquivo? UNICODE ou ANSI?