# Caracter Especial aparece em Minúsculo - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte página PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Consulta de OP's por OP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        zoom: 80%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cadastro'])){ 
        if($_SESSION['permite_visualizar'] == 0){
            ?>
            <script language="JavaScript"> 
                window.location="inicial.php"; 
                window.alert("Acesso Negado! Sem permissão!");
            </script> 
            <?php
        }   
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita";
        ?> 
        <script language="JavaScript"> 
            window.location="index.php"; 
            window.alert("Area Restrita");
        </script> 

        <noscript> 
            Se não for direcionado automaticamente, clique <a href="index.php">aqui</a>. 
        </noscript>
        <?php
    }
    include_once("navbar_op.php");
    ?>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1 align="right">Apontamento de OP's&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</h1>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <h4 align="center">Consulta por OP</h4>
    <form method="get" align="center">
        <label>OP: </label>&nbsp<input type="text" name="ops" placeholder="Digite a op a Pesquisar">
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
        <input type="text" name="pagina" value="1" hidden>
    </form>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dropdown">
                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Exportar
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="exporta_excel_por_op.php">Excel</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PDF</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TXT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $total_reg = "30";
    $pagina=$_GET['pagina'];
    if (!$pagina) {
        $pc = "1";
    } else {
        $pc = $pagina;
        $inicio = $pc - 1;
        $inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;
    }


    if(isset($_GET['ops'])) {
        $ops = $_GET['ops'];
    }

        $_SESSION['ops'] = $ops;
        //$ops2 = $_SESSION['ops'];
    $todos = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM MT_OPS 
        WHERE OP LIKE '%$ops%' ORDER BY CRIACAO DESC");

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM MT_OPS A
        WHERE OP LIKE '%$ops%'  ORDER BY CRIACAO DESC LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");

    $lmite = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    $tr = mysqli_num_rows($todos);
    $tp = $tr / $total_reg;

    ?>
    <?php 
    $anterior = $pc -1;
    $proximo = $pc +1;
    if ($pc>1) {
        echo " <a href='?pagina=$anterior&ops=$ops'><- Anterior</a> ";
    }
    echo "|";
    if ($pc<$tp) {
        echo " <a href='?pagina=$proximo&ops=$ops'>Próxima -></a>";
    }

    ?>


</p>
<div class="responsive-table">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>OP</th>
            <th>Lote</th>
            <th>Qualidade Inicial</th>
            <th>Qualidade Final</th>
            <th>Referência</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Quantidade Peças</th>
            <th>Pçs /Hora</th>
            <th>Operadores</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Hora Início</th>
            <th>Hora Término</th>
            <th>Minutos Parados</th>
            <th>Motivo Parada</th>
            <th>Lanche</th>
            <th>Excluir</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $sequencial = $linhas['SEQUENCIAL'];
                $qualidade = $linhas['CONTROLE_QUALIDADE_INICIAL'];
                $qualidade_quebrada = wordwrap($qualidade, 10, '<br>', true);
                $qualidade_fi = $linhas['CONTROLE_QUALIDADE_FINAL'];
                $qualidade_quebrada_fi = wordwrap($qualidade_fi, 10, '<br>', true);
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['OP']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['LOTE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>";echo $qualidade_quebrada;"</td>";
                echo "<td>";echo $qualidade_quebrada_fi;"</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['REFERENCIA']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['DESCRICAO']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['QTD_PECAS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['PECAS_HORA']."</td>";
                echo "<td height='45'>".$linhas['OPERADORES']."</td>";
                echo "<td style='width: 110px'>".$linhas['DATA']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['INICIO']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['FIM']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['PARADA']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['MOTIVO']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$linhas['LANCHE']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=''>Excluir</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='edita_op_por_op.php?sequencial=$sequencial&op=$ops'>Editar</a></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>   
    <?php
    $anterior = $pc -1;
    $proximo = $pc +1;
    if ($pc>1) {
        echo " <a href='?pagina=$anterior&ops=$ops'><- Anterior</a> ";
    }
    echo "|";
    if ($pc<$tp) {
        echo " <a href='?pagina=$proximo&ops=$ops'>Próxima -></a>";
    }
    ?>      
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu tenho outra tela em que as referências são cadastradas e ele cadastra tudo em maiúsculo no banco de dados. Porém, quando abro a página acima, a descrição fica com o caractere especial em minússculo, por exemplo: `CAMINHãO`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue dizer por quê isso acontece ou uma correção para isso?

Comment: amigo usa a função strtoupper() do php.

Comment: Poderia mostrar como está no banco de dados esse caractere?

Comment: Desta forma está no banco: prntscr.com/jzka7y

Comment: @Maikeaerosmith Este `Ã` que aparece no banco não é o `Ã` da sua palavra; seu banco está com problema de codificação, provavelmente por estar mal configurado. Veja mais em [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/5878).

Comment: Consegui com a ajuda do @MayconF.Castro, usando mb_strtoupper($linhas['DESCRICAO'], 'UTF-8')

Comment: @Maikeaerosmith Mas isso não resolverá seu problema, só o mascará. Corrija as codificações do seu projeto e não terá mais problema com isso na vida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta

```
echo "<td>".mb_strtoupper($linhas['DESCRICAO'], 'UTF-8')."</td>"
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Continou aparecendo minusculo :(

Comment: Se ajuda, no banco de dados está dessa forma: http://prntscr.com/jzka7y

Comment: Tenta essa aqui mb_strtoupper($linhas['DESCRICAO'], 'UTF-8');

Comment: Deu certo, muuuuuuitisssimo obrigado!!!

Comment: Amigo se puder pontua a resposta e marca como correta.

Comment: Prontinho! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado tbm amigo, qualquer coisa só comunicar.